# Odd'em out: letters

Tags: code-golf, sorting, matrix, alphabet

### Objective

Write a program or function (or equivalent) that sorts out and returns the odd letter in the matrix of random size.

### Details

You will be passed a matrix (as a string) as input of random dimensions such as this.

```
bbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbdbbbb
bbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbb
```

Your job is to find the letter that doesn't match the rest (in this case, it is `d`, found at line 2, col 6) and to return that letter as output. The matrix will consist of letters `A-Z`, `a-z`, newlines (`\n`, only on ends of rows) and have dimensions ranging from 5x5 to 10x10 (25-100 letters).

Standard loopholes apply. This is a code golf challenge;  entry with code of least bytes wins.

### Input

Input will be passed in through standard input as a string if it is a program or as an argument if a function (or similar).

### Output

A single character that is the "odd" in the matrix *or* `None`, `nil`, `NUL`, or the string `"None"` if there is no "odd" character.

### More Examples

```
AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA
AAAIAAA
AAAAAAA
```

Answer: `I`

```
vvqvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvv
vvvvvvvvvv
```

Answer: `q`

```
puuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuu
uuuuuuuuu
```

Answer: `p`

### Generator

Here is a random matrix generator written in Python that you can use to test your program. **Note:** There is a slight chance that it could make a mistake and not put in an odd letter.

```html
Instructions

1. Copy this code into a file called `matrix_gen.py`.
2. Run it with `python matrix_gen.py`.

---

from random import randint

rows = randint(5,10)
cols = randint(5,10)

charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
neg = charset[randint(0,51)]
pos = charset[randint(0,51)]
p_used = 0

comp = 0
matrix = ""

while comp < rows:
  row = ""
  while len(row) < cols:
    if not p_used and not randint(0,10):
      p_used = 1
      row = row + pos
    else:
      row = row + neg
  row = row + "\n"
  matrix = matrix + row
  comp += 1

print matrix[:-1]
```

Comment: [Here](https://tio.run/##hZBJT8MwEIXv/hUmhyolImqRysXtgX0t@74ImcRNUhw7td2mQPPbg52YoB4QF2v05hu/eTPGMywDkWRqjfGQlKXguYQDOMQq9gVmIU/d9uqG11t0EAg4/bMHghgLSZTuO/gtCMkoipPxO00ZzyZCquksn398bm5t7@zu7R8cHh2fDE/Pzi8ur65vbu/uHx4dBBiJ9LT952nZpbe@6LwgkHH5L/I6lSTUVLUUT7O6TLESydxsp51AHieUuFW3D03kNvwC0FSWgLBGtOJTwiIVa9Dkr0EIk5G7Yq1areWT9P3uDwVhs04XWcWYeAOoo9RKUb2EStIMWUQf5BcpQKM7z6xa0WbSim4YwQTyPAQKHZxJTolPeeTWWBuV5Tc) is a literal translation of your Python code into JS.

Comment: @juniorRubyist "removing the bonus" isn't the same as "making the bonus mandatory". By moving the part that was optional so far into the requirements of the challenge, you've invalidated a large part of the existing answers.

Comment: Just let people output whatever if there's no character.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda x:min(x,key=x.count)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjczT6NCJzu10rZCLzm/NK9E839BUWZeiUaahpKSUllZYRkEcJXBAUEmUKOm5n8A)

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>12 10</s> 7 bytes

```
-.}./.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT0FXr1ZPX6/uf2pyRr5CmkJxSUpmnrr6/1IY4EJhpWIRI5cFAA)

```
    /.~        Group identical items together
  }.           Remove one item from each group
-.             Remove the rest from the input
```

#### 10 byte version

```
-._1 1{\:~
```

<sup>hisss...</sup>

```
       \:~        Sort down
  _1 1{           Take the last character (which is a newline) and the second one.
-.                Remove those from the input
```

Comment: @ FrownyFrog This is a clever way to find the odd character

Comment: can’t decide what i like better: this lovely hook or your dragon joke...

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>8</s> 4 bytes

```
oḅ∋≠
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/P//hjtZHHd2POhf8/6@UCARJiYlciRCAi1b6HwUA)

### Explanation

I haven't used Brachylog before, so this may not be optimal.

```
oḅ∋≠  Input is a string.
o     Sort the input.
 ḅ    Split it into blocks of equal elements.
  ∋   There is a block
   ≠  whose elements are all different.
      That block is the output.
```

Comment: That use of `∋≠` after `ḅ` to get the results of length 1 is very clever. You should definitely post it in the [Brachylog tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/108296/tips-for-golfing-in-brachylog).

Comment: @Fatalize Thanks, I added the tip.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>4</s>  2 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Adnan*

```
.m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fL/f/fyUlpSQ44AKTKQhmEm4mUCMA)

**Explanation**

```
.m   # push a list of the least frequent character(s) in input
```

Comment: Do you need to remove the newlines, seeing as we're guaranteed the input will be at least 5 lines long?

Comment: @Shaggy: No I don't. That was to handle `2x2` matrices. I missed the part about `5x5` and up. Thanks!

Comment: It has to return `nil` if it doesn't have an "odd one out" doesn't it?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn That part was optional when this answer was posted. I guess that change invalidates most answers now...

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

**Solution**

```
*<#:'=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X8tG2UrdVqmsrLAMAmLyyuCAGLbS//8A)

**Example:**

```
*<#:'="vvqvvvvvvv\nvvvvvvvvvv\nvvvvvvvvvv\nvvvvvvvvvv\nvvvvvvvvvv"
"q"
```

**Explanation:**

Found a slightly shorter approach: Evaluated right-to-left:

```
*<#:'= / the solution
     = / group matching items together
  #:'  / count (#:) each (')
 <     / sort ascending
*      / take the first one
```

**Notes:**

Whilst I'm expecting the bonus aspect of this challenge to get dropped, this solution will return the newline character `\n` if there is no odd character:

```
*<#:'="vvvvvvvvvv\nvvvvvvvvvv\nvvvvvvvvvv\nvvvvvvvvvv\nvvvvvvvvvv"
"\n"
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>93</s> <s>92</s> <s>90</s> <s>66</s> 62 Bytes

Much shorter as a function

```c
t;f(char*p){for(t=*p;*p;)t^*p++?putchar(*p^*--p?*p:t),*p=0:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tUxBCoQwELv3FR5nRgtedRAfIgpStq4HdbDTk/j2rl32CxtCSEiIs4tzKSl7cO/5JMHLHydoR8IPUSeSsuwlaq6BZCJrpSdpFSuSrm5rvtM2rzuguUzxIA@LMDTNyN@c/3h5aYCAjD6ruZPEH0z8l/sA)

test code

```c
main()
{
    char s[99];
    for(;gets(s);)f(s);
}
```

old version is a program

## C 86 Bytes

```c
char*p;s[9];main(t){for(;p=gets(s);)for(t=*p;*p;)t^*p++?putchar(*p^*--p?*p:t),*p=0:0;}
```

Outputs the odd character, or nothing.  run like this;

```c
C:\eng\golf>python matrix_gen.py | a.exe
X
C:\eng\golf>python matrix_gen.py | a.exe
G
C:\eng\golf>python matrix_gen.py | a.exe
x
C:\eng\golf>python matrix_gen.py | a.exe

C:\eng\golf>python matrix_gen.py | a.exe
J
```

Comment: I don't know that it is quite fair to put the `gets()` into the test driver as it is sanitizing the input by removing the \n chars for you.  That's doing some work so that your function is not working on the original input.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It works with the piped input from the python script as well as input on TIO.  Others simply hard-coded the input which didn't seem with the spirit of the challenge.

Comment: Suggest `*p=!putchar(*p^*--p?*p:t)` instead of `putchar(*p^*--p?*p:t),*p=0`

Answer (score 3):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 46 bytes

```
p(L):-select(X,L,Y),\+member(X,Y),writef([X]).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/v0DDR9NKtzg1JzW5RCNCx0cnUlMnRjs3NTcptQjIB/LKizJLUtM0oiNiNfVA6hOSQCAmD51KgfMSNPUA)

Or if the standard **true** output from prolog queries is not okay:

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 48 bytes

```
Z*L:-select(X,L,Y),\+member(X,Y),char_code(Z,X).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P0rLx0q3ODUnNblEI0LHRydSUydGOzc1Nym1CMgH8pIzEovik/NTUjWidCI09f7/j9BKSAKBmDx0KgXOS9ADAA)

**Explanation**

```
Find the first element X in the input  
that when removed, results in output  
that does not contain X

then depending on the version above either:  
print X as a character  
or  
return X as an atom
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 94 bytes

Return by pointer. If none, return `\0`.

This will cause memory leaks. Assuming `int` is 4 bytes.

```c
*t;f(c,p,i)char*c,*p;{t=calloc(64,8);for(*p=-1;*c;c++)t[*c]--;for(i=0;++i<128;)!~t[i]?*p=i:0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nUxBDoIwELzzirWntpQEiTHGlXDyFcihbII0UWlqPRH4OlbQqybOYWcyOzOUnImmSXpsOCmrjKBWO0lKWux9Tvpy6YhvN2onsOkclzZP1igJKY6FLyVVSTI/TJ5iHJvDOtuhWI2@NFURwmaf4jARn1dBC@jhJaEuswpyYClDaLhWUAsE@/B3PsoaCqhhD@zoHAv2EEVXbW5cRH0EAcsALpozPeN0C8e/WX/jMPmptj@iX6r6j@owPQE)

Comment: [Functions must be reusable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4940/58974).

Comment: @Shaggy Actually, I don't know how to interpret that rule, as I see some (other) users explicitly know about that rule but still post such answers like this one.

Comment: @user202729, just because others do it doesn't mean it's right ;) If you spot such solutions, best to point it out to them.

Comment: @Shaggy Well, I explicitly pointed the rule but that user said "the rule explicitly says that this one is valid". I don't know what to say. | In this case the function require the array `t` be zeroed before calling each time not the first time.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 27 bytes

```
Last@*Keys@*CharacterCounts
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yexuMRByzu1sthByzkjsSgxuSS1yDm/NK@k@H9AUWZeiUNatFISHHCByRQEMwk3Uyn2PwA)

*-1 byte from Martin Ender*

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 13 bytes

```
s(O`.
(.)\1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P@/WMM/QY9LQ08zxlCb6/9/RwjgwkJ7IvEB)

#### Explanation

```
s(O`.
```

Sort all characters.

```
(.)\1+
```

Remove any characters that appear at least twice.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>15</s> 20 bytes

```bash
fold -1|sort|uniq -u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py0/J0VB17CmOL@opKY0L7NQQbf0//88KOAiyPDMAwA)

**Explanation:** `fold`s the input to `1` character per line, `sort`s it into groups of matching letters, then prints only lines that are `uniq`ue.

*Thanks [@Nahuel Fouilleul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70745/nahuel-fouilleul) for catching and helping fix a problem with this approach.*

Comment: doesn't work if the odd character is the second or the penuitlimate

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Good catch... I'm unsure of how to fix that at the moment, but I will fix or delete later unless you had a suggested fix.

Comment: it can be simply fix with `|sort|` but there may be a better solution

Comment: also found a solution with grep but it's longer `grep -oP '^(.)((?=(?!\1).){2}|.*\K(?!\1).)'`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I'm going with the `sort` fix, thanks. You could always post that grep answer as your own if you want to, though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 2 bytes

```
◄=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9H0Ftv///8nwQEXmExBMJNwMwE)

This is a function taking a string as input and returning a character. It takes the minimum of the input string when comparing characters for equality (i.e. it returns the character that is equal to the least number of other characters).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

Returns `null` if there's no odd letter.

```js
s=>s.match(`[^
${s.match(/(.)\1/)}]`)
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>s.match(`[^
${s.match(/(.)\1/)}]`)

console.log(f(
  'bbbbbbbbbb\n' +
  'bbbbbdbbbb\n' +
  'bbbbbbbbbb\n' +
  'bbbbbbbbbb\n' +
  'bbbbbbbbbb'
))

console.log(f(
  'AAAAAAA\n' +
  'AAAAAAA\n' +
  'AAAAAAA\n' +
  'AAAIAAA\n' +
  'AAAAAAA'
))

console.log(f(
  'vvqvvvvvvv\n' +
  'vvvvvvvvvv\n' +
  'vvvvvvvvvv\n' +
  'vvvvvvvvvv\n' +
  'vvvvvvvvvv'
))

console.log(f(
  'puuuuuuuu\n' +
  'uuuuuuuuu\n' +
  'uuuuuuuuu\n' +
  'uuuuuuuuu\n' +
  'uuuuuuuuu\n' +
  'uuuuuuuuu\n' +
  'uuuuuuuuu\n' +
  'uuuuuuuuu\n' +
  'uuuuuuuuu\n' +
  'uuuuuuuuu'
))

console.log(f(
  'AAAAA\n' +
  'AAAAA\n' +
  'AAAAA\n' +
  'AAAAA\n' +
  'AAAAA'
))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
ċ@ÐṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9It8PhCQ93Nv3//z8RArhARBKUBgIA)

Return `\n` (a single newline) in case there is no odd character. Obviously `\n` is not a printable character.

Coincidentally this is exactly the same algorithm as Mr.Xcoder Python answer. (I came up with it independently)

Explanation:

```
  ÐṂ    Ṃinimum value by...
ċ@      ċount. (the `@` switch the left and right arguments of `ċ`)
```

That works because in a `m×n` matrix:

- If there exists odd character: There are `m-1` newlines, 1 odd characters and `m×n-1` normal character, and `1 < m-1 < m×n-1` because `5 ≤ m, n ≤ 10`.
- If there doesn't exist odd character: There are `m-1` newlines and `m×n` normal character, and `m-1 < m×n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 4 bytes

```
ho/Q
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ho%2FQ&input=%22ggg%5Cnegg%5Cnggg%22&debug=0)**

Comment: `.m/Q` is 4 bytes as well

Comment: @Dave That outputs as a list though, I chose this because it was more elegant ;-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>6</s> 4 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ü l1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=/CBsMQ&input=ImJiYmJiYmJiYmIKYmJiYmJkYmJiYgpiYmJiYmJiYmJiCmJiYmJiYmJiYmIKYmJiYmJiYmJiYiI)

```
ü l1     :Implicit input of multiline string
ü        :Group & sort
  l1     :Filter elements of length 1
         :Implicit output of last element
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 17 + 3 (-00p) -25% = 15 bytes

```
/(.)\1/;s/
|$1//g
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19fQ08zxlDfulhfxbCGS18//f//JDjgApMpCGYSbua//IKSzPy84v@6BgYFAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe)*

```matlab
@(x)x(sum(x(:)==x(:)')<2)
```

Anonymous function that takes a 2D char array as input, and outputs either the odd letter or an empty string if it doesn't exist.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzQqO4NFejQsNK09YWRKpr2hhp/k/TiFZ3hAB1awXcTE800VjN/wA)

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 33 * 0.75 = 24.75 bytes

```
f s=[c|[c]<-(`filter`s).(==)<$>s]
```

Returns an empty list if there's no odd character.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02h2DY6uSY6OdZGVyMhLTOnJLUooVhTT8PWVtNGxa449n9uYmaegq1CSr4Cl4KCQkFRZl6JgopCmoJSIgjE5CGoZBQeiFIipCWRWC2K@LT8BwA)

For each char `c` in the matrix (given as a string `s`) make a string of all chars in `s` that are equal to `c` and keep those of length 1.

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 47 bytes

```
(lambda(s)(find-if(lambda(x)(=(count x s)1))s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74r1FQlJmXrKDxXyMnMTcpJVGjWFMjLTMvRTczDSZSoalhq5GcX5pXolChUKxpqKlZrKn5X8nR0ZELjAsdlYB8AA)

Returns the odd letter or NIL if it does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>91</s> <s>86</s> <s>82</s> <s>79</s> 71 bytes

```c
f(char*s){for(;*++s==10?s+=2:0,*s;)if(*s^s[-1])return*s^s[1]?*s:s[-1];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY7BjsIgEEDP5SsmJCYD1aT1KCGe/AqtCWJZmyi7YaqXpt9eKerBi7u6c2BmHvMY7OzL2mFwaA8mSBKd@w6oZJ6T1mWxpFzPF8VUkhKNQ0lbWs/KSoS6PQef2rJaSlokrPphf3sHjIAOWDY2sFvPK9DAC64ianwLF3OMwKERiThMQEMhWJb9nFtCvgqBC8Wy@kj1CEP0HPKJ3Xg@jePxrmfsZBqPgnUMYtyWqVTvkZsUGx@P9p7Nqzyuu6uHX0ZfqA90@lz9U949q6t/f/gdtR@u)

- Thanks to **Gastropner** for the xor and ? tricks (-3 bytes)
- Reworked the compare version to fix bugs and used **Gastropner** magic from comments.

**Explanation:**

Compare current and previous char while skipping newlines.  If different, compare to next char.  This tells us if we return current or previous char.  The function returns the "odd" char value if it exists or 0 if the array is not odd. We get away with the "next" char check because there is always a newline before the `\0` char.  If there is no odd char, we intrinsically return the \0 from the for loop.

---

**Older, sexier xor code Explanation:**

Make a running xor mask of the next 3 string values.  If they are all the same, then the value will be equal to any of the three.  If they are different, then the 2 identical will cancel each other out leaving the unique.

Must factor /n before the xor or it gets messy.
Also have to check 2 chars for inequality in case s[0] is the odd value.  This costs the extra || check.

```c
v;f(char*s){while(s[3]){s[2]==10?s+=3:0;v=*s^s[1]^s[2];if(v^‌​*s++||v^*s)break;}}
```

Comment: 79 with a few tweaks. The fall-through return does not agree with my compiler, so only tested on TIO: `v;f(char*s){while(s[3]){s[2]==10?s+=3:0;v=*s^s[1]^s[2];if(v^*s++||v^*s)break;}}`

Comment: For the crap I am writing, TIO is what I stick with.  Thanks!

Comment: Rearranging some expressions allows another -2 for 77: `v;f(char*s){while(s[2]==10?s+=3:0,v=*s^s[1]^s[2],s[3])if(v^*s++||v^*s)break;}`

However your winning horse is the other one, if you fiddle with it a bit, for 73: `v;f(char*s){for(v=-1;*++s==10?s+=2,v--:0,*s;v=0)if(*s^s[-1])return s[v];}`

Comment: Yeah, but the xor seems so sexy.  :)

Comment: Suggest `s+=*++s-10?0:2` instead of `*++s==10?s+=2:0`

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, 25 Bytes

```
a=input('');a(a~=mode(a))
```

The input "a" where "a" isn't the mode of "a".
Outputs empty array for no oddball.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 85 bytes

This is a lambda from `String` to `String` (e.g. `Function<String, String>`). It's essentially a copy of [Luca's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149371), but I've pared down the string sorting a bit.

```java
s->new String(s.chars().sorted().toArray(),0,s.length()).replaceAll("(.)\\1+|\\n","")
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##jVFNT8MwDD2vv8LKKRFdBFfGJk1InEAcOFIOXpttKVlSJe5QBf3tJaUVaB8Si6LYennv2XFK3OPUVcqWxXtX1Sujc8gNhgBPqC18JpMRDIQUw1pbNFBGlaxJG7mubU7aWfkwJncv5LXdpDDERa8onoviUREpD/MuTBdWfYzXPMh8iz5wIYPzpIqYkFt6jw0X6XUapFF2Q1suhPSqMpirpTGccSmy7ObqK8ssSxkT3WSWHLe6d7qAXXwFH2q9vgH6TRD9oya/UI5BBZjDX08R7BkjRZYuOrC@zhGHYb8ifJisThBkrUgvclwd6v7LLrU93@i51gfHdhaPtfMwTg7wPk4JbodhiXE8TSC1k64mWUUSGcsPvlpiVZmG/0iF6B3bJO62@wY)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 54 bytes

```cs
i=>i.GroupBy(x=>x).FirstOrDefault(g=>g.Count()<2)?.Key
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY3BSsRAEETv8xV9nAGdg9dssuCuK4uKooLncdLGwWx37J5ZN8h@ewyi4A9Yl6qioF7U08iCU9FEHTyMmnFXmb/NXyd6r4yJfVCFO@FOwg4@DcBQnvsUQXPIs@05tXATEln3vQKsmJR79E@SMs4vaAk/YFMoLjTLTDiB@Bpk2dgp1U3yl8JlOB/toW4Ozm@SaL6VNb6E0mfb1U3nV1woW7c4c0t/hePk/Jb2/Ib2F7Ulf4@hfeQLaq1zrjoep6H8yJT/Sl8)

Comment: You are right, my answer was wrong. I have deleted it. But you are missing the 18 bytes from the `using` statement in the byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
|!
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7C%21&i=%22%22%22%0AAAAAAAA%0AAAAAAAA%0AAAAAAAA%0AAAAIAAA%0AAAAAAAA%0A%22%22%22)

Answer (score 0):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 16 * 75% = 12 bytes

```
/-.nDo&
\i..*N@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/19fVy/PJV@NKyZTT0/Lz0H//39HCODCQnsi8QE)

Outputs `Jabberwocky` if there is no duplicate character.

#### Explanation

```
/...@
\.../
```

This is a framework for linear programs that operate entirely in Ordinal (string processing mode). The actual code is executed in a zigzag manner and unfolds to:

```
i..DN&-o

i   Read all input.
..  Make two copies.
D   Deduplicate one copy, giving only the two letters and a linefeed.
N   Multiset difference. Removes one copy of each letter and one linefeed.
    Therefore it drops the unique letter.
&-  Fold substring removal over this new string. This essentially removes
    all copies of the repeated letter and all linefeeds from the input,
    leaving only the unique letter.
.   Duplicate.
n   Logical NOT. Turns empty strings into "Jabberwocky" and everything else
    into an empty string.
*   Concatenate to the previous result.
o   Print the unique letter or "Jabberwocky".
```

Instead of `&-`, we could also use `ey` (transliteration to an empty string). Alternatively, by spending one more character on stack manipulation, we could also deduplicate the input which lets us remove the unwanted characters with `N`, but it's still the same byte count:

```
i.D.QXN.n*o@
```

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 13 bytes

```
/N.-D@
\i&.o/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fT0/XxYErJlNNL1///39HCODCQnsi8QE)

This is the solution without the bonus, it's simply missing the `.n*`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 22 bytes

```
!`(.)(?!.*\1)(?<!\1.+)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fMUFDT1PDXlFPK8YQSNsoxhjqaWv@/@8IAVxYaE8kPgA) Only requires height and width of at least 3, rather than 5.

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 16 bytes

```
(1=+/a∘.=a)/a←,⎕
```

Prompts for screen input and either outputs odd letter or nothing if there is no odd letter

Comment: `a/⍨1=+/a∘.=a←,⎕` for a byte

Comment: @Uriel Thanks but I am afraid the operator ⍨ is not available in my old APL+WIN version 5 :(

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 39 bytes

```powershell
([char[]]"$args"|group|sort c*)[0].Name
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyM6OSOxKDo2VkklsSi9WKkmvSi/tKCmOL@oRCFZSzPaIFbPLzE39f///@pJcMAFoVIQzCScTHUA)

Takes input as a string with newlines (as specified in the challenge), converts it to a `char`-array. We then `Group-Object` the characters, so that characters are grouped together by their names, then `sort` based on the `c`ount. This ensures that the lonely character is first, so we take the `[0]` index and output its `.Name`.

If newline is acceptable for "nothing" then this qualifies for the bonus.

Comment: I was hoping `sort c*)[0]` could be shortened, but what I came up with was the same number of bytes, `? c* -eq 1)`.

Comment: can be shortened by removing the double quotes around `$args`. Also it is more accurate to do `([char[]]$args|group|? c* -eq 1).Name` as it will accurately return `null` when there is no odd character (instead of new line). However in terms of bytes this still won't bring you below 37.

Comment: @cogumel0 Doesn't run without double quotes.

Comment: @root you're correct. However to pass one of the requirements (A single character that is the "odd" in the matrix or `None`, `nil`, `NUL`, or the string `"None"` if there is no "odd" character.) it should still be changed. Newline is not part of the acceptable answers.

Comment: @cogumel0 Ah, the challenge was changed since I posted my answer. The "None / nil / whatever" used to just be a bonus rather than mandatory. I'm going to keep my answer as-is.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork thx for the explanation, now it's clear why your solution was posted that way.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>27</s>  24 -25% = 18 bytes

```perl6
*.comb.Bag.min(*.value).key
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##tU@7TsQwEOz3K1anCDkhcSSKKwiJgC4NDXSEIg@DrMvDZzs@ouO@jI4fC7kk9ygQVIy09ozXu5oRTJbLvlUMzZLmAVQdXuRNwTDsHZo3VUbv0zda8Zo41KRly2y6Yl0/frzVTGkM0XLiB6rKVgqqJa@oEiXXxMekvsQbkmzsCJ9H8YEWvvguXpuh1IoLj1VCd/bXJ33UMoC9jadhZwCiTOt5v49XAbw2cpZehBavRatdtNi7YLlmBW4BkSvcGydT1z5ru7jYTq9jIuInG98ec6lGauIdkg02hmw7DKPT7AJ2fXYEjGdxotkvtIC7CT/d8bmOwZi1mQDmiL/pGkQ7A9p/Y@Ib)

```perl6
{%(.comb.Bag.invert){1}}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##tY@7TsMwFIb38xRHVUBOSRzB0IGQCNiysMBGGXIxKGourm8lCnkyNl4sNBe1HRBMfJLt//exj/7DmShWvZYMzYqmPpQNnqd1xjDo2zNC07pM6H38RvPKMKHs9rLr@vHVrWJSYYDWMnqgstCCUyXykkpe5Ip4uK4u8Iasd3aIz6P5QAtfPAevzX7JTc5dVnLV2F@f9FEJH4YMT/uePvAirub@Hl758FqL2bohWnnFtXLQYu@cpYpl2AJiLnFITaaqfVJ2cNFOt@MwxFvvPHscSdZCEXdJTVxoNsTYsKbDIDz@XUDXJwdg3LOjTH6RGdxN/HRGpz4CY7ZmAsyBv@UWuJ4B/W@KfwM)

This will [return an undefined value](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7X1qcqlBmppdszZVbqaCWnJ@SqmD7v1pVQy85PzdJzykxXS8zryy1qESz2rC29j9YlUpJanGJgq1CoVVJvr6rn4u@NVciGOClgAq5uIoTKxVSUtMy81JTFEB2aYDN0vwPAA) when given an input that doesn't have an odd character out.

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  %(        # coerce into a Hash

    .comb   # split the input into graphemes (implicit method call on ｢$_｣)
    .Bag    # turn into a weighted Set
    .invert # invert that (swap keys for values) returns a sequence

  ){ 1 }    # get the character that only occurs once
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>93</s> <s>98</s> 108 bytes

```java
a->{char[]r=a.toCharArray();java.util.Arrays.sort(r);return String.valueOf(r).replaceAll("(.)\\1+|\\n","");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY8xT8MwEIX3/IqTJ0dQS8xRkSKmDpShY93hkrjg4F6CY1uqQn57MGlUdYCIhTfYn59Pd@9qDLhqWkV19T6WBrsOnlFTnwBocsoesVSw/X4C7JzV9AqKz4BpFv0hiUfn0OkStkCwhhFXj335hnZ/sGsUrnmKnFuLZ55mdRwovNNGTE4nusY6btPMKuctzUNEQOPVyzF@CKtaE1PkxnDGRSrlw92nlMTuGUuzYcyS1hcmDp8zhEZXcIo7zDH3hxgU@mR37pw6icY70UbfGeIkFGdYICJL4y6/VRRXSZqu6oaLJV5sm18k6UfY3DqLfUL4CBdJClf9hRfbtn6WJP/fOAUZhvEL)

The input is converted to an array of characters, which is then sorted. We have to make a string again so we can replace all occurences matching the regex.

I first tried to simply do it with one "replaceAll" but I did not manage to create a regex that would delete the first a in "abaa" for example.

Comment: I think what you're looking for in the first two statements is `char[] r = a.toCharArray(); Arrays.sort(r); a = new String(r);`; the existing code doesn't actually do anything to `a`. This should fix your solution for cases like `abaa`.

Comment: @Jakob the code does something. It converts a string to a char array and sorts it, then it changes it back to a string and replaces everything appearing more than once. If I managed to create a regex matching cases like `abaa`I could leave out the part converting the string to an array etc.

Comment: Nope. The first statement sorts a copy of the string's character array and discards it, and the second statement passes `a` through `String.valueOf(Object)`, which leaves it unchanged.

Comment: @Jakob I don't have any words for this... I am sure I tested it and it was working in my tests but I simply feel stupid now, of course it discards the copy... Thank you

Comment: @Jakob fixed, but it costs 5 bytes... I should stop trying to submit Java solutions, in part because I seem to be an idiot :D

Comment: No, by all means keep golfing! The more you practice, the better you'll get.

Comment: One more thing: lambda solutions can't use imports without including them in the byte count, so you'll have to either add in an import for `Arrays` or use the fully-qualified name in your lambda.

Comment: @Jakob oh man, didn't think about that... plus another 10 bytes ^^ but hey, at least it's valid now :P and thank you for encouraging

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 61 bytes

```r
cat(names(sort(table(unlist(strsplit(scan(,""),""))),T))[-1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCMvMTe1WKM4v6hEoyQxKSdVozQvJ7O4RKO4pKi4ICcTyEhOzNPQUVLSBGFNTZ0QTc1oXcNYzf9JcMCFykzEKgoF/wE)

Takes input from stdin, outputs the letter (or the empty string) to stdout.

Explanation:

```r
x=scan(,"")                     # read in input
x=unlist(strsplit(x,""))        # split into characters
x=table(x)                      # tabulate character counts
x=sort(x,T)                     # sort into decreasing order
x=names(x)                      # get the names (the characters)
x=x[-1]                         # remove the first element
cat(x)                          # print out the remaining letter (or nothing if none exist)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Brainfuck, 125 bytes

```
,[----------[>],]<[->+<]<<[[->->+<<]>[>[->-<<<+>>]>[,<<,>>]<<<[->+<]>[->+<]<]>[-<<+>>]>[-<+>]<<<<]>>>>[<]<++++++++++.
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##tY1BCoAwDATvvsTSVvS@5COhBxUEEUSEvr9usPYHziWTZEOWe97PLa9HKUH7aYwNp5JCgkbxSIBSTJFExRyAF2EXgEBh/2alnph8mchqCQ6JcstfvuGGUq5c6fJf9gA)

Prints the letter of the matrix if there is no odd one out

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 74 bytes

**normal program, 57 bytes:**

```php
<?=chr(array_search(min($a=count_chars($argv[1],1)),$a));
```

(prints a newline if the is no odd character)

**modified program, 74 bytes:**

```php
<?=count($a=count_chars($argv[1],1))<4?None:chr(array_search(min($a),$a));
```

(assumes Windows linebreaks; replace `4` with `3` for input with Unix linebreaks)

Run with `php <scriptname> '<matrix>'` or [try then online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f267b56ed3f632f34e9cc8d0912a24dd220cb8ea).

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.chars.min_by{|c|s.count c}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1664ulgvOSOxqFgvNzMvPqmyuia5BiiSX5pXopBcW/u/oLSkWCEtWj0PArjykBieGCJgoB77HwA)

Uses the same idea as [Mr. Xcoder's great Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/149321/69583).

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 36 bytes

```arturo
$[s][select s'c->one? match s~"|c|"]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?jpI9rd)

Answer (score 0):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 17 bytes

```
~.{~[:(i.<./)#/.~
```

Outputs the odd character or LF.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxsU6vui7aSiNTz0ZPX1NZX68OIn6L0VSTKzU5I19B3VNdQddKIQ2k24DLEQKw0Z7IfJjmQmTNZWWFZRDAVQYHhJkwswqQzSoohQKuUpqxoBb7uCHZmwgCOElNSOgtWAChAQ)

```
~.{~[:(i.<./)#/.~
    [:             NB. [: f g forces f(g(y))
             #/.~  NB. character frequency
      (i.<./)      NB. monadic hook
         <./       NB. minimum
       i.          NB. index of minimum in frequency list
  {~               NB. index from
~.                 NB. unique characters
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `DD`, \$ 10 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 8.23 bytes

```
dcZZz;AKAK
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_WbSSi4tS7IKlpSVpuharUpKjoqqsHb0dvSECUPGl0UrhSrE3zZLggAtMpiCYSbiZEDMA)

##### Explanation

```python
dcZZz;AKAK  # Implicit input
dc          # Count of each character
  ZZ        # Zip with input
    z;      # Reverse-sort this list
      AKAK  # Last item of last item
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
æcḅ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMyVBNmMlRTElQjglODUmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD1BQUFBQUFBJTBBQUFBQUFBQSUwQUFBQUFBQUElMEFBQUFJQUFBJTBBQUFBQUFBQSZmbGFncz1X)

##### Explanation

```python
æcḅ  # Implicit input
æ    # Filter by:
 c   #  Count in input
  ḅ  #  Equals one
     # Implicit output
```

Comment: 10 chars with two flags in Thunno 1, 3 bytes flagless in Thunno 2. Lol

Comment: @noodleman ikr so much progress :p Enjoy your holiday btw