# Longest Increasing Substring

Tags: source-layout, self-scoring

Given a list of positive integers, write code that finds the length of longest contiguous sub-list that is increasing (not strictly).  That is the longest sublist such that each element is greater than or equal to the last.

For example if the input was:

\$[1,1,2,1,1,4,5,3,2,1,1]\$

The longest increasing sub-list would be \$[1,1,4,5]\$, so you would output \$4\$.

Your answer will be scored by taking its source as a list of bytes and then finding the length of the longest increasing sub-list of that list.  A lower score is the goal. Ties are broken in favor of programs with fewer overall bytes.

Comment: Is it okay to return true instead of 1? And do we have to handle an empty list?

Comment: For your first one, whatever meta consensus is on numeral output you may do, I don't recall `True` being a substitute for `1` but it may be.  You should be able to handle the empty list (Output is of course 0).

Comment: Suggested test cases: `[] => 0`, `[0] => 1`, `[3,2,1] => 1`, `[1,2,1,2] => 2`

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the 'score' a bit more?

Comment: @ouflak I'm not sure what more there is to say on the score. Convert your submission to a list of bytes and pass it through your own program and that's your score. If scores are equal, the tie-breaker is the bytecount

Comment: You really should add those test cases. It seems like a majority of these answers don't handle the empty list case correctly.

Answer (score 7):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), score 2 (8 bytes)

```
lefSIT.:
```

[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lefSIT.%3A&input=%22lefSIT.%3A%22&debug=0)

Code points `[108, 101, 102, 83, 73, 84, 46, 58]`. Another shorter solution, `leSI#.:` scores 3, but its code points are `[108, 101, 83, 73, 35, 46, 58]`, which are very close to a score of 1, actually. <s>Rearranging a bit may help</s> Nevermind, the substrings built-in is `.:` which cannot be rearranged, so the lowest score must be 2 if the program makes use of it.

#### How?

```
lefSIT.:     Full program. Accepts either a list or a string from STDIN.
      .:     Substrings.
  f  T       Only keep those that are...
   SI        Sorting-Invariant.
le           Length of the last item.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>score 3, <s>53</s> 46 bytes</s> score 2, <s>51</s> 50 bytes

-7 bytes thanks @Arnauld

<s>+5</s> +4 spaces in exchange of -1 score

```javascript
a=> a.map($= p=n=>$=(p<=(p=n)?++ x:x=1)<$?$: x)&&$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcpLCsIwFIXhuasIJZRcEgPxMSm9LbiNUmiovdJSk9CqZPdRcaI4OD9n8E32Ydd@GcNt6/x5SITJYsWsvtogOLKADiuOIpSvoYNaShaLiAZKXvOCRchznnrvVj8PevYXQaIxyqidevegjmr/@S3A5ts1WuvTnWhYRJZJglZPfnQd634Z/UOA9AQ)

Assumes non-empty input. 61 bytes if empty list must be handled. Score 2 still.

```javascript
a=> a.map($= p=n=>$=(p<=(p=n)?++ x:x=1)<$?$: x)&& a.length&&$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc5NCoMwEAXgfU8RJIQMpgH7sxFHodcQwWCTVrFJUFu8fWpx09LSxTwej28xnXqosRlaP22tO@tgMCjMiZI35TlF4tFiTpH7bDm0UMQxmdMZE8hoQVMyA2OL7rW9TFfGaGicHV2vZe8u3PAyEYnYiVcexFHs114BbN5dKaU83Y3RA4@i2EAlO9famtSfzHxD@CfWp6JfapnCEw)

...or 58 if returning `false` is allowed. Score 2 still.

```javascript
a=> a.map($= p=n=>$=(p<=(p=n)?++ x:x=1)<$?$: x)&& a>[ ]&&$
```

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQCPXtsA2z9Yu11ajwAaIbfM07bW1K6wqbA01bXLtc60qNNXUcv8n5@cV5@ek6uXkp2ukaUQb6hjqGOmASBMdUx1jCDtWU5MLTZ2enp4SaTYpxYLVJtvaJeslZyQWOQPd61iioQkE/wE) should work for 46 bytes and the same score.

Comment: @Arnauld added 5 spaces to your suggestion so that it's now a score 2

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), score 2, <s>66</s> <s>64</s> <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 65 bytes

- -2 bytes thanks to [Max Yekhlakov](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/82142/max-yekhlakov)
- -1 byte thanks to [nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34531/nimi)
- +5 bytes to handle the empty list

```hs
foldr1 max.g
g[]=[0]
g(x:y:z)|x>y=1: g(y:z)
g(_:y)|a:b<-g y=1+a:b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzPy0/J6XIUCE3sUIvnStdo8Kq0qpKs6bCrtLW0EohXQPMS7RKstFNVwGybQ21gRyudIV422jD2P@ZeQWlJbZKyGbE5BFpCFAhxBQlrtzEzDzbgqLMvBKVNAWwmf//JaflJKYX/9dNLigAAA) (verifies itself).

I never thought I could get a score of 2 with Haskell, and yet here I am!

Function `g` computes the lengths of all the increasing substrings recursively.
`foldr1 max.g` takes the maximum of those lengths (`foldr1 max` is equivalent to `maximum`, but with a lower score).

Comment: Looks like the whitespace in `1+a : b` is not necessary, so this is 62 bytes.

Comment: @MaxYekhlakov You're right, I don't know how I missed that.

Comment: Your code returns `1` for the empty list, where it should return `0`

Comment: @Jo King Indeed, I had missed the discussion in the comments. Fixing that right now.

Answer (score 4):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage), score = 2

```
00000000: bc6d 4cdc 14                   ▲mLġ≥
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9G0Tbk@RxY@6lz6////aEMLCx1DA0sdczMdIyMDHSODWAA)

It's unlikely to get a score lower than 2 with Husk because `ġ`<sup>1</sup> has a really high codepoint and there needs to be something before it to get the maximum and length. An attempt could be made with trying to use multiple functions but `\n` would be before any helper functions which has a really low codepoint so anything after it would create an increasing byte-sequence of at least length 2.

<sub>1: This seems like the best way to use for the comparison operators would need to follow the various split functions like `↕` (`span`).</sub>

#### Explanation

```
▲mLġ≥  -- example input: [1,1,2,1,1,4,5,3,2,1,1]
   ġ≥  -- group elements by geq: [[1,1,2],[1,1,4,5],[3],[2],[1,1]]
 mL    -- map length: [3,4,1,1,2]
▲      -- maximum: 4
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), score 2, 13 bytes

```
d0< ~Y'w)X>sQ
```

Input can be:

- An array of numbers.
- A string enclosed with single quotes. Single quotes within the string are escaped by duplicating.

MATL uses ASCII encoding. The codepoints of the above code are

```
100, 48, 60, 32, 126, 89, 39, 119, 41, 88, 62, 115, 81
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8XARqEuUr1cM8KuOPD/f3UoHyqgDgA)

#### Explanation

```
d     % Implicit input. Consecutive differences (of code points) 
0<    % Less than 0? Element-wise. Gives true or false
      % Space. This does nothing; but it breaks an increasing substring
~     % Negate
Y'    % Run-length encoding. Gives array of true/false and array of lengths
w     % Swap
)     % Index. This keeps only lenghts of runs of true values
X>    % Maximum. Gives empty array if input is empty
s     % Sum. This turns empty array into 0
Q     % Add 1. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 40 bytes, score 3

```
\d+
$*
(?<=(1+)),(?!\1)
¶
T`1`_
^O`
\G,?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LUw5DgIxDOz9CySKhJ0iXpvsRgKlpKShjGCRoKChQLyNB/CxEEdI1ngOj1/39@N5rbXcBlpvyOXd3vHgPVxeFfb0/dBp4eVC5@NC5YBcaxrBIUClLUiEmoYGREFsyMY12YFyH/2nImhli9gqPPfmrEjR3IZpa05STF0aHzH1F1F@) Link includes itself as byte codes as input. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
(?<=(1+)),(?!\1)
¶
```

Split on decreasing pairs.

```
T`1`_
```

Delete the digits.

```
^O`
```

Sort the commas in reverse order. (I would normally write this as `O^` but can't do that here for obvious reasons.)

```
\G,?
```

Count the longest comma run, and add one to include the final number.

Answer (score 3):

## Japt `-h`, 6 bytes, score 2

Don't *think* a score of 1 is possible. Should work with strings & character arrays too.

```
ò>¹mÊn
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8j65bcpu&input=WzI0Miw2MiwxODUsMTA5LDIwMiwxMTBdCi1o) - included test case is the charcodes of the solution.

---

### Explanation

```
ò          :Partition after each integer
 >         :  That's greater than the integer that follows it
  ¹        :End partition
   m       :Map
    Ê      :  Length
     n     :Sort
           :Implicitly output last element
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), score 2

111 bytes

```pascal
var a,b,c,t:bYte;bEgIn repeat read(a); iNc(c); if a<b then c:=1; if c>t then t:= c;b:= a;until eOf;write(t)eNd.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVBLb4MwDP4rPlKJTTGEPGDdbYdduvOOIQ0dUoUQTbefz2KHrZW2iw2f/T2c2V28Oz8Ms1/XT7eAK/vSl7Ht32Po@pfT6wRLmIOLqblj4XYdjAdfeOoDuKce4keYwLd7ZMQ/x4zEdg@@61N13XWK4xnC29B9LWMMRdyFw/FxXRENWA2IEuqKvqQEa7haqogKGkOQsfyDAqGxBKgEiBp0nXBBbBKhMWLFnXXV/YQQIUAKdmIhmooGtGFDwfV@gKLakilBrqxGMX682DqxUkqFIO0/XAuqukX5Q95uTOxNic@7IZoQRM37mU/aOUuS0ZadeMlutza/jyUzJx3Fuya/gIJv)

Assumes non-empty input. Numbers are taken from standard input separated by spaces.

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), score 2, 46 bytes

```perl6
{my&g=1+*×*;+max 0,|[\[&g]] [ |@_] Z>=0,|@_ }
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwvzq3Ui3d1lBb6/B0LWvt3MQKBQOdmuiYaLX02FiFaIUah/hYhSg7W6CgQ7xC7X9rruLESoU0jWhDHUMdIx0QaaJjqmMMYcdqIskbAUWNUcWQ2AhmYQJpbkjQS81Lzk9J1XMsKkqs1LT@DwA)

Handles the empty list. The original code was:

```perl6
{my&g=1+*×*;+max 0,|[\[&g]] @_ Z>=0,|@_}
```

So only 5 extra bytes to reduce the score to 2.

Edit: Ah, I figured out how to [remove the assignment](https://tio.run/##hY5NDoIwGET3nOIzENJiQ/hRNwSi17A2QKBEE1q0GpUA5/BAHqyCLli6mbzMLOaduao3WrRgVxCD7kyRP8Ho6YHaaOEtnffLwYwBhX6bMtgnsUdGgkGbiovmzqFohODyBrksQfJHfZLcuOYtVIj6xCcBmXJF1iT8McPRvAdjG85dRytkpXj8AStNErc4qi8O6JJ1k9h/r8zlsmhK7u6Uylsc6Q8), but then I can't get that score below 3 because of the `)]]`...

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                  }  # Anonymous code block
 my&g=     ;  # Assign to &g an anonymous Whatever lambda
      1+*×*   # That multiplies the two inputs together and adds 1
                            @_ Z  0,|@_   # Zip the list with itself off-set by one
                                >=        # And check if each is equal or larger than the previous
                                         # e.g. [5,7,7,1] => [1,1,1,0]
                    [\[&g]]  # Triangular reduce it by the function declared earlier
                          # This results in a list of the longest substring at each index
                          # e.g. [5,7,7,1] => [1,2,3,1]
            +max 0,|      # And return the max value from this list, returning 0 if empty
```

Comment: So `[[&(*+*)]]` works like `[+]`? Amazing...

Comment: @nwellnhof Yeah, there's a few caveats like you can't have any whitespace (*at all*), but you can even use it with `Z` and `X`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7/784sVLBUMdIx1ghIlpNQ6tCQUtbRVtbM1bBGChoaM2FkI8CyddpgGTrtBAKlBVASqLBkkoKSiCpWKgOZYW8fIXyjMyS1OKCxORUBSuN//8B "Perl 6 – Try It Online")

Comment: I was going to try something like: `{max 0,|.[[X..] ^$_ xx 2].map({+$_ if [<=] $_})}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), score 2

<sup>There is probably a score 1 solution somehow...</sup>

```
IṠµṣ-ZL‘
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z4c4Fh7Y@3LlYN8rnUcOM////R5sb6ygYGZjqKFgCaSMgxwTENtBRMDcDCpgaxQIA)**

Source code as a list of byte values:

```
[73, 205, 9, 223, 45, 90, 76, 252]
```

#### How?

```
IṠµṣ-ZL‘ - Link: list of integers  e.g. [ 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]
I        - increments                    [ 0, 1,-1, 0, 3, 1,-2,-1,-1, 0]
 Ṡ       - sign                          [ 0, 1,-1, 0, 1, 1,-1,-1,-1, 0]
  µ      - start a new monadic chain (a low byte to stop score being 3)
    -    - literal minus one             -1
   ṣ     - split at                      [[0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [], [], [0]]
     Z   - transpose                     [[0, 0, 0], [1, 1], 1]
      L  - length                        3
       ‘ - increment                     4
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score 3 (9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage))

```
Œʒ¥dP}éθg
```

Can most likely be a score of 2 somehow.

Code points of the program-bytes: `[140,1,90,100,80,125,233,9,103]` (two sublists of length 3: `[1,90,100]` and `[80,125,233]`)

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6KRTkw4tNfBOCag9vPLcjvT//6MNdQx1jHRApImOqY4xhB0LAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
Œ            # Sublists
 ʒ   }       # Filter by:
  ¥          #  Take the deltas
   d         #  Check for each whether the number is >= 0
    P        #  And check if it was truthy for all deltas
      é      # Then sort by length
       θ     # Take the last element
        g    # And take its length as result
```

Answer (score 1):

## Powershell, score 3, 44 bytes

```powershell
($args|%{$i*=$_-ge$p;$p=$_;(++$i)}|sort)[-1]
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {

(
    $args|%{        # for each integer from argument list
        $i*=$_-ge$p # -ge means >=.
                    # This statement multiplies the $i by the comparison result.
                    # A result of a logical operator is 0 or 1.
                    # So, we continue to count a current sequence or start to count a new sequence
        $p=$_       # let $p stores a 'previous integer'
        (++$i)      # increment and return incremented as length of a current sequence
    }|sort          # sort lengthes 
)[-1]               # take last one (maximum)

}

@(
    ,(4, 1,1,2,1,1,4,5,3,2,1,1)
) | % {
    $e,$a = $_
    $r = &$f @a
    "$($r-eq$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 4
```

Explanation:

- The script takes integers as argument list ([spaltting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting)).
- Each integer maps by a function to legnth of `contiguous sub-list that is increasing (not strictly)`. Then the script sorts lengthes and take a last (maximum) `(...|sort)[-1]`.

---

### Powershell 6, score 3, 43 bytes

```powershell
$args|%{$i*=$_-ge$p;$p=$_;(++$i)}|sort -b 1
```

Same as above. One difference: `sort -b 1` is shortcut for `sort -Bottom 1` and means [1 element from the end of sorted array](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-6). So we need not an index `[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), score 3, 94 bytes

```java
a->{int m=0,p=0,x=0,i=0,n;while(i<a.length){n=a[i++];m=(p<=(p=n)?++x:(x=1)) <m?m:x;}return m;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZJNj4MgEIbv/opJYxqIlm7346LSZi9766nHpgfWqqUraBBbG@Nvd4GYTffjuglD9IV5h3ngzC5scT5@jFzUldJwNv@k1bwkr0qxWxN7XlqypoEt4xJ6D7jUmcpZmsH29tbKVPPK6XYBciMg87E/AMOxB4MHjWaap/eb8/hLtXk5UFguGV0zIliNfFpTSdc@RXVigkq8CYIu6ugKJ/7Gjzo8n/sjW6x7W1DQh7A20ZngJmR8PfEyQzxhpMxkoU@4l5TteRAcYvHDE1lTDInYiKiLB5XpVkkQ8TACfDv8peJHKKtiaq3B7uC7W6MzQapWk1qZlVKinDgCDZ6ar9v30uTf2wjDEe20SSgsJVVMbtZeZldwJfpVCGY8utmM5xBeQnj6UgbrDxNow2/2vzxmJD0x1SBMdOWeBXL180qBRQIcInPfYKRfUBCHAGYwcwl/EHO67X16L8P4CQ)

Port of my (with suggestions from Arnauld) JS answer. `etu` in `return` and `hil` in `while` make it impossible to golf to score 2.

`for` cannot be used here because:

- `;for` is ascending
- `for` cannot be used at the beginning of the lambda body (scope restrictions). It is possible to wrap it with `{}` but apparently using `while` saves bytes.

Comment: I was going to suggest possibly using `\u` in some places, but then you have to have `00` followed by a digit which is 3 anyway...

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), score 3 (15 bytes)

```
Z|[F|]F:^!C_%|M
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=Z%7C[F%7C]F%3A%5E%21C_%25%7CM&i=[1,1,2,1,1,4,5,3,2,1,1]%0A[]%0A[0]%0A[3,2,1]%0A[1,2,1,2]%0A%22Z%7C[F%7C]F%3A%5E%21C_%25%7CM%22&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>score 5, 87 bytes</s> score 2, <s>101</s> <s>93</s> <s>92</s> 101 bytes

```python
lambda a,m=1,o=[1]:max(reduce(lambda B,c:[B[:-m]+[B[-m]+m],B+o][c[0]>c[m]],zip(a,a[m:]), o)) *(a>[ ])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVG7csMgEKzNV1wHREQTpdRELlzkJwgFgpNF9EADeOLk5xVky5Mm1cLtwd7uLd@p9/PrarxFaCBQStdRT63VoMXUVMI3slL1pK8soL0YZDt7EqaWJ1k/T6rIuMGkxKnwShr5oo5GTkqJH7cwLbScasUFeM7hiemjBMXXrFTGFHIDJwSvaIB2DS22QQhZgpsTdGx0MbFJL8wHKzaKc/7HSvW47CX67gOkHiHqAcF3kL5QD24@C@gx4AeNN9b0l3mIZVlSQix2cGaa1wTaRkqdZ1eKQJc/MsKCm@HhocoeanJwHdg3kw@HtmkLKW1uP@AYcS/lSKocSStvsLEQMOZsJcuOP72bb4ZMH4ThXIw4s4x3wU2uzQ92N6MOZ4zpPi@4SMV9D1HAgN/NvglTm7wivsmkS5g3tUdE538DXH8B)

Ooops! Thought this was code-golf first time through...

Comment: Score of 5. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY0xDgIhEEX7PcV0MFkssCR6EjIFLEskcYGMmKiXx/EQVr94/7/f3@PW6nmmPUPWwcSrt4RugdwYNpOgVPiULiR464RIIXp3srRK/sKSiauMyKfLRgvwPp5c4QgvHXF2LnWI@V4eQx@h68bJKKX@9CdmRJzzCw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: Indent with tabs to get a score of 4.

Comment: @mypetition: D'oh! Thought this was code golf... editing my answer now.

Comment: Funny that [removing the `m=1,o=[1]` part](https://tio.run/##bZCxcsMgDIbn8BTagAv1NR19dYcMfQnKgEG2qR3sA3JN@vIuOO516cBJp1/ol77lnobZv6xmtggNBErpOulLazXo@qJvLKC9GmR77SxMLc@yfjqBOuZki/mJ81GeFChp5LN6M1suvt3CtNDyVIPiAnKR8zUbVDGFLHFC8IYGaNfQY/EnZAnOJ@jY5GJiF72wOVhRJM75ru499H0OkAaEqEeEuYP0hXp0vhcwYMAPGjfVDFc/xqqqKCEWO@iZ5jWBtpFS502VItDlQUZYcB7@Fla56@A6sK8mJ4e2aY9S2tx@wCniXioYMoVWbqGoEDBmipLlIz9n57cbzBCE4VxM6FmOD8Ni1@YP@zWTDj3G9NgXXKTiwT4KGPHe7PRNXcjyYpOuwRe3X2b9v8zWHw) doesn't end up saving any bytes once we reduce the score

Comment: @Jo King: Chuckle! I kept hoping that by squirming in that way, I could chip off another byte; but no such luck!

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](https://www.dyalog.com/), score 2, 20 bytes

```apl
{⍵≡⍬:0⋄⌈/≢¨⍵⊂⍨1,2>/⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/pR79ZHnQsf9a6xMnjU3fKop0P/UeeiQytAwl1Nj3pXGOoY2ekDebX/H/VNfdQ2gXgNhrpAHlCTY9ij3s3qxOtT5yLZJh0gUwdEmuiY6hhD2P8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), score 3, 45 bytes

```
Max[Length/@SequenceCases[#,x_/;OrderedQ@x]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78H1CUmVcS/d83sSLaJzUvvSRD3yE4tbA0NS851TmxOLU4WlmnIl7f2r8oJbUoNSXQoSI2Vu2/g4JzRmJRYnJJalFxtBJJepViY/8DAA)

`SequenceCases` and `OrderedQ` by themselves give a score of 3, so the score can't be improved without changing the approach significantly.

Comment: The correct way to use patterns would have us do `Max[Length/@SequenceCases[#,_?OrderedQ]]&`, but `_?Or` is an increasing subsequence of length 4. (As is `_?AnyCamelCaseCommand`.)

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin, Score 6,  119 bytes**

```
 fun x(a : IntArray){var m=1;var k=0;var d=1;while(k<a.size-1){if(a[k]<=a[k+1])m++;else{if(d<m)d=m;m=1};k++};println(d)}
```

[Try Online](https://rextester.com/live/ORBXZ48091)

Explanation

1. Step 1: Check for previous value to next value
2. Step 2: If previous value is less or equal then add plus 1 keep doing while condition 
   is true
3. Step 3: check previous count with next count, keep highest count in variable d.

Comment: Ok, i got it, i will edit it shortly.

Comment: Please check, i have made a function in which input can be given.
As per my sample string answer would be [2,4,5,6,7,7,7] Score is 7.

Comment: I have updated score and link please check.

Comment: Ok, I gave updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84168/discussion-between-jo-king-and-syed-hamza-hassan).

Answer (score 0):

## Java (JDK), 126 bytes, Score 6

Golfed

```
private static int l(byte[] o){int m=0;int c=1;int p=0;for(byte i:o){if(m<c){m=c;}if(i>=p){p= i;c++;}else{c=1;p=0;}}return m;}
```

Ungolfed

```
private static int longest(byte[] input) {
    int maxc = 0;
    int consec = 1;
    int prev = 0;
    for (byte i : input) {
        if (maxc < consec) {
            maxc = consec;
        }
        if (i >= prev) {
            prev = i;
            consec++;
        }
        else {
            consec = 1;
            prev = 0;
        }
    }
    return maxc;
}
```

Input

```
[112, 114, 105, 118, 97, 116, 101, 32, 115, 116, 97, 116, 105, 99, 32, 105, 110, 116, 32, 108, 40, 98, 121, 116, 101, 91, 93, 32, 111, 41, 123, 105, 110, 116, 32, 109, 61, 48, 59, 105, 110, 116, 32, 99, 61, 49, 59, 105, 110, 116, 32, 112, 61, 48, 59, 102, 111, 114, 40, 98, 121, 116, 101, 32, 105, 58, 111, 41, 123, 105, 102, 40, 109, 60, 99, 41, 123, 109, 61, 99, 59, 125, 105, 102, 40, 105, 62, 61, 112, 41, 123, 112, 61, 32, 105, 59, 99, 43, 43, 59, 125, 101, 108, 115, 101, 123, 99, 61, 49, 59, 112, 61, 48, 59, 125, 125, 114, 101, 116, 117, 114, 110, 32, 109, 59, 125]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `byte` be `int`, since `byte` would be restricted to 8 bits?

Comment: @JoKing I am not exactly sure what you mean. Do you mean that I should change the byte class to int class?

Comment: Yes, since the input is a list of integers

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin, Score 4, 67 bytes

```
{a:IntArray->var i=0;var p=0;a.map{if(it<p){i=0};p=it;(++i)}.max()}
```

Main idea is: Transform each integer to length of contiguous sub-sequences that is increasing (not strictly). Return maximum.

- `a.map{...}` - for each integer in the array do
- `if(it<p){i=0}` - if current integer is less then a previous integer, then reset counter
- `p=it` - store current integer in the previous
- `(++i)` - increment counter and return value of the expression
- `.max()` - get maximun of all length

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 64 bytes

```ruby
->e{e.size.downto(1).find{|l|e.each_cons(l).find{|c|c==c.sort}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y61OlWvOLMqVS8lvzyvJF/DUFMvLTMvpbompyZVLzUxOSM@OT@vWCMHJpxck2xrm6xXnF9UUltb@7@gtKRYIS062lDHUMdIB0Sa6JjqGAPZxmCWGUgsNvY/AA)

Comment: Note that this is not [tag:code-golf]. Your current score is `6`. Also, your code does not handle the empty list (where the output should be `0`)

Answer (score 0):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), score: 2 (8 bytes)

```
⊇L≤₁&sLl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FXu8@jziWPmhrVin1y/v@PNtQx1DHSAZEmOqY6xhB27P8oAA)

This code, according to [Brachylog’s code page](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki/Code-page), is the following string of char codes / integers:

```
[08, 4C, 03, 80, 26, 73, 4C, 6C]
[8, 76, 3, 128, 38, 115, 76, 108]
```

[Which results in a score of 2.](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FXu8@jziWPmhrVin1y/v@PttBRMDfTUTDWUTA0ArKNgdjQ0BQiaGhgEfs/CgA)

#### Explanation

```
⊇L         L is a sublist of the input (trying from longest to shortest)
  L≤₁       L is increasing
     &sL    L is also a contiguous sublist of the input
        l   Output the length of L
```

We need to use `⊇` to get the longest sublists first and then check that it is contiguous with `s`, because `s` does not try them longest first (see [this Brachylog tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/231602/41723)).

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), score 4, 172 bytes

```go
type y=int
type x=[]y
func f(q x)y{l,o:=*new(x),*new(x)
for _,e:=range q{n:=len(o)
if n>0&&o[n-1]>e{if len(l)<n{l=o}
o=append(*new(x),e)}else{o=append(o,e)}}
return len(l)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=1VJLTsMwEJXY1acYdVHFyEUtHwlFdU_QBfuqolFxSlTXTmM3tIp8EjYVgh0n4CZwGsZxUgo3QIo8ma_fm-fnl6U-fOTJYpUsBayTTJFsnevCwkU3Xdvu29am_dvPd7vPBex5piypf3d8OtuTdKsWkEYb2NF9JZmO-bkST9GOssaSVBdwz0TMi0ThBZtKxVwKFWlKshTUeNDr6anqD2djUWHApyQdqUpy7YjmSZ4L9RC1UwV1QhpRHRPahxwphN0Wqul2AfPX2WuZFLACDh5mNJnOED2tz4p0pEY8xjINMYcQdKyxpPMH9gQbOg08TccD6PVAT4MXsGO-LWgmUxg19VBn2xsRj_a-84fm4UrhvcAthE_4kboWv5ZlmEMcCVLkYGyxXSCpxSMSRidTS1ImErxaWFWr5KWNPJTdD-EhG7JL5s9rdsOuwr8jdzjAShWtcOX06KW1R4xvn_-n5zBH0DKQzlHb0pwo3gLyoQDJeLWwnkMz00gGeRW2GgnKsA-NQ1lw0rGqNAxChpKfDRpJT7ZZml_rrN3msR4OwX4D)

I'm pretty sure this is the absolute minimum this bit of code can achieve, because `=int` is ascending in terms of value.

If you change `y` to be `rune`, and `x=[] y` you then get hung up on `\nfor`. Unless someone finds a way to make case-insensitive keywords in Go, then 4 is the minimum score.