# Is It Mountainous?

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

## Challenge

For this challenge, a mountainous string is one that conforms to the grammar rule `M: x(Mx)*` where at each production, the all x's are the same character. When indented, a mountainous string might look something like this:

```
A
 B
  C
   D
  C
   E
    F
   E
  C
 B
A
```

As you can see, it looks a bit like a mountain from the side.

## Formal Definition

- Any single character `a` is mountainous.
- If `S` is a mountainous string and `a` is a character, then `aSa` is mountainous, where juxtaposition represents string concatenation.
- If `aSa` and `aTa` are mountainous strings, then `aSaTa` is a mountainous string. Note that this rule implies that this pattern holds for any number of repetitions. (i.e. `aSaTaUa`, `aSaTaUaVa`, `aSaTaUaVaWa`... are all mountainous.)

## Examples

All odd-length palindromes are mountainous, for instance:

```
t
 a
  c
   o
  c
 a
t
```

`qwertytrasdfdgdsarewqjklkjq` is a less trivial example:

```
q
 w
  e
   r
    t
     y
    t
   r
    a
     s
      d
       f
      d
       g
      d
     s
    a
   r
  e
 w
q
 j
  k
   l
  k
 j
q
```

## Example Outputs

```
a                           ==> true
aaa                         ==> true
mom                         ==> true
tacocat                     ==> true
qwertytrasdfdgdsarewqjklkjq ==> true
wasitacaroraratisaw         ==> true
abcbcbcbcba                 ==> true
aaaaabcbbba                 ==> true

<empty string>              ==> false
aa                          ==> false
pie                         ==> false
toohottohoot                ==> false
asdfdghgfdsa                ==> false
myhovercraftisfullofeels    ==> false
```

## Rules

- This is a decision problem, so any representation of true or false is valid output as long as it is correct, consistent, unambiguous, and the program terminates in a finite amount of time. Be sure to state your output convention with your solution.

  - It should be trivial to determine whether the output indicates true or false without having to know what the input string is. Note that this does not mean the truthy or falsy outputs have to be constant, however the convention of "print a mountainous string if the string is mountainous and a non-mountainous string if not mountainous" is a banned loophole for obvious reasons.
  - On the other hand, a convention like "throws an exception for false and exits silently for true" would be fine, as well as "prints a single character for true and anything else for false"
- This is code golf, so the shortest program wins.
- Standard loopholes are banned.

Comment: A test case like `aaa` would be good, where the same character needs to be used on multiple levels.

Comment: Are you sure about `wasitacaroraratisaw` ? It seems mountanous to me

Comment: `wasitacaroraratisaw` is indeed [mountainous](https://pastebin.com/W5YvqUxF) AFAICT

Comment: So it is. I guess I was just trying to find an 'almost palindrome', but I found a mountainous string by accident.

Comment: I thought this would be easy to solve by splitting the string on its first character, but cases like `aaa` make that not work.

Comment: You can solve it with a recursive descent parser. I believe a parser generator would also work.

Comment: Can we assume the input only contains lowercase ASCII characters?

Comment: I think something like `abcdedfghgedcba` should be in the falsey test cases (the second `e` would match the height of a preceding `e` during construction, but there is built mountain in the way, while if the second `e` were an `f` instead the string would be mountainous - or indeed if the `f` were an `e`).

Comment: "any representation of true or false is valid output as long as it is correct, consistent, and the program terminates in a finite amount of time." actually does not clearly define a line before a no-op ("returns a mountainous string when mountainous and not otherwise") which would clearly be a loophole. (note that "consistent" does not imply anything about being constant). I'd recommend requiring at least one of the two output sets to be singular as well as the outputs being consistent. (this is why using ["truthy vs falsey"](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/53748) is easiest).

Comment: @Zgarb no. Even though I only use lowercase examples, it should work with all 8-bit strings. A lot of languages will handle unicode just fine, but I would rather hit the least common denominator. Whether it works or not for unicode does not matter.

Comment: @JonathanAllan "print the string for true and nothing for false" is fine. I see no reason for it to have to be constant. For instance, you could make it so the program throws an exception for true and does nothing for false. Or you could use return codes where 0 is true and nonzero is false. Or you can send out real missile alerts for true and test alerts for false. Whatever convention you want to use is fine as long as it's unambiguous.

Comment: Sure but my point was that at least one of the two outpurs should be required be fixed across runs, "print the string if true and nothing if false" fits that but "prints a mountainous string if true and not otherwise" does not and the latter allows a noop.

Comment: 'the convention of "print a mountainous string if the string is mountainous and a non-mountainous string if not mountainous" is a banned loophole for obvious reasons.' As long as your convention isn't a copout in that same vein, it's allowed.

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt v2](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
e/.).\1/_g
¥g
```

[Test it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ZS8uKS5cMS9fZwqlZw==&input=ImFiY2JjYmNiY2JhIg==)

Answer (score 8):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>94</s> <s>89</s> <s>87</s> 80 bytes

```
import StdEnv
?[a,b,c:s]=[a: ?if(a==c)s[b,c:s]]
?l=l
$s=limit(iterate?s)==[hd s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lcu9CsIwFIbhPVcRsNAK9QYKIYsOglvH0OGYpvVAfiTn1OLNGwM6fMvL81nvIJaQ5s07GQBjwfBMmeXI8yW@hDbQ33s70KQMDFLj0oFS9kjmVyehvfKiIeUxIHfILgM7TUelzGOWNJWRIbM4SOKMcZVKmnYHQgYLOWWoHAn2dqpk2aJlTLGiRtT9P@VjFw8rldP1Vs7vCAEtfQE)

Answer (score 6):

## Perl, 22 bytes

Includes `+` for `p`

```
perl -pe '$_=/^((.)((?1)\2)*)$/' <<< abcbcbcbcba
```

Prints 1 for true, nothing for false

Answer (score 5):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 78 bytes

```
({()<<>(([{}]({}))([{}]({}))<>[({}<>)])>{[()()]((<()>))}<{}{}{}<>>}(())){{}}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYdBCsMwDAS/s3vID4Q@YnxQcRIah4KdQAhCb3fTU5nDzLy6vT/TslsdAw6KKJA8MjzIf4mmx6LMVE8gmAEBlQzx@CGqAZB0j2fHaNfcz/vsdpSlrOWwPl9tq3vd2pjsCw)

Prints 1 for true, nothing for false.

To verify a mountainous word, it is sufficient to assume the word goes "down" the mountain whenever possible.

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 29 bytes

```
a-->[X],+X.
+X-->[];a,[X],+X.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P1FX1y46IlZHO0KPSzsCxIm1TtSBigClNRIKy1OLSipLihKLU9JS0lOKE4tSywuzsnOyswoTdKJjNfW4uAA)

This program defines a DCG rule `a//0` that matches any string (list of characters) that is a mountainous string.

### Explanation

For this program I use a slightly different but equivalent definition for mountainous strings than what is described in the challenge: A mountainous string is a character `c` followed by a number (could be zero) of mountainous strings with `c` tacked onto the ends of them. In a more terse regex derived notation, a mountainous string must match the pattern `c(Mc)*` where `M` is a mountainous string and `*` means that the expression in parentheses is repeated zero or more times. Note that while each `c` must be the same character, each `M` does not need to be the same mountainous string.

#### Proof of Equivalence

It is clear that rules 1 and 2 from the challenge are equivalent to my rule where `Mc` occurs zero and one times respectively.

In the case that the mountainous string has `Mc` occurring `n` times where `n > 1` then the string can be rewritten as `cMcSc` where `S` is the latter `n - 1` times that `Mc` occurs excluding the last `c` (note that `M` is any mountainous string and not necessarily the same as other `M`). Since `M` is a mountainous string, by rule 2, `cMc` must be a mountainous string. Either `S` is a mountainous string in which case `cSc` is a mountainous string or `S` can be rewritten as `cMcTc` where `T` is the latter `n - 2` times that `Mc` occurs excluding the last `c`. This line of reasoning can keep on being applied until string not guaranteed to be mountainous contains `Mc` once which would mean it would have to be mountainous as well. Thus since `cMc` is mountainous and if `cMc` and `cM'c` are mountainous then `cMcM'c` must be mountainous the whole string must be mountainous.

For the converse, for a string `cScTc` where `cSc` and `cTc` are mountainous then either `cSc` is a mountainous string by rule 2 or by rule 3. If it is a mountainous string by rule 2 then `S` must also be a mountainous string. If it is a mountainous string by rule 3 then `cSc` must be of the form `cUcVc` where `cUc` and `cVc` are mountainous strings. Since the longer of `cUc` and `cVc` must still be at least two characters shorter than `cSc` and rule 3 requires at least 5 character to be applied then after a finite number of applications of rule 3 each string between the `c`s selected by applications of rule 3 must be a mountainous string. The same line of reasoning can be applied to `cTc` thus the string is mountainous by my definition.

Since any string that matches my definition is mountainous and my definition matches all mountainous strings, it is equivalent to the one given in the question.

#### Explanation of Code

Overall the `a//0` DCG rule, defined on the first line, matches any mountainous string. The `+//1` DCG rule (like predicates, [DCG rules can be give operator names](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153160/20059)), defined on line two, matches any string that is made up of a sequence of zero or more mountainous strings with the character passed as its arguments `X` tacked onto the ends of them. Or to borrow the regex-like notation I used above, `a//0` matches `c(Mc)*` but outsources the job of actually matching the `(Mc)*` to `+//1` which takes `c` as its argument `X`.

Line by line the codes behaves as follows:

```
a-->[X],+X.
```

This line defines the DCG rule `a`. The `[X]` states that the first character must be equal to the currently undefined variable `X`. This results in `X` being set equal to the first character. The `+X` then states that the rest of the string must match the DCG rule `+//1` with the character that `X` is set to as its argument.

```
+X-->[];a,[X],+X.
```

This line defines the `+//1` DCG rule. The `;` represents an or in Prolog which means that the string can match either `[]` or `a,[X],+X`. The `[]` represents the empty string so `+//1` is always capable of matching the empty string. If the string is not empty then the start of it must match `a//0` and so must be a mountainous string. This must then be followed by whatever character `X` is set to. Finally the rest of the string must match `+X`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>89</s> 83 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:re.search(M,s)and f(re.sub(M,r'\1',s))or len(s)==1
import re;M=r'(.).\1'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY/BbsMgDIbP61NwI5GqSO2xE3uDPkG3g5NAoSU4sWmjPH1mkk1INvx88gfjkj2m87o6E2Foe1B8IduwBep8dT1yDalXrirZq5WA9PdJS1wjqWhTxbUxp0MYRqSsyH5eDemqqRuhVicMq5DUTYM@Kg2wtQGH0jJ02EEu22m2lJdMwL3r7z0D2Xl6POPzMZXrGTgIDYQEBDkwzNu4tvtb/9OhRO1@3KNSx2A3H6LHnKXgJt1l/u7Etz1r8fi21BE4UbhXjOisjax/LoePkULKigUzXwI7@ff6Cw)

Thanks to ovs for 6 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
εωφΓ§?t·:⁰`(=←t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYw7DsIwEET7PQVluAIS4ipsHDvOx1pib7BShiISHRKHoKUB@hwguUMuYsxHI43mSaOnW1eFlUnccurX4zNMj/k8D9N1vO14fG2W/r5Ptstw4RACAiKCIQOMggQyNF5a7tiiy1SWZw6t9E1Z1VXZgEdXxB9asmiRC4ceMBX/fF344TTuCHAoJDCRJuZYxPCT6lxFL5hO01FaYVFFlWrrmpSUtXsD)
Type inference takes about 40 seconds, so be patient.

### Explanation

```
εωφΓ§?t·:⁰`(=←t  Implicit input, say s = "abacdca"
 ω               Apply until fixed point is reached
  φ              this self-referential anonymous function (accessed with ⁰):
                  Argument is a string x.
   Γ              Deconstruct x into head h and tail t.
    §?t·:⁰`(=←t   Call this function on h and t. It is interpreted as §(?t)(·:⁰)(`(=←t)).
                  § feeds h to (·:⁰) and (`(=←t)), and calls (?t) on the results.
                  The semantics of ? cause t to be fed to all three functions.
          `(=←t   First, check whether h equals the first element (←) of the tail of t.
     ?t           If it does (e.g. if h='a' and t="bacdca"), return tail of t ("acdca").
                  Otherwise (e.g. if h='b' and t="acdca"),
       · ⁰        call the anonymous function recursively on t: "aca"
        :         and prepend h to the result: "baca".
                 Final result is "a".
ε                Is it a 1-element string? Implicitly print 0 or 1.
```

The idea is to repeatedly replace a substring of the form `aba` with `a` until this is no longer possible.
The input is mountainous if and only if this results in a single-character string (which is what `ε` tests).
The only dangerous situation is when we have a string like this, where `aba` doesn't seem to be a peak:

```
a
 b
  a
   c
  a
   d
  a
 b
a
```

Fortunately, we can always transform it into one:

```
a
 b
a
 c
a
 d
a
 b
a
```

Comment: I believe returning a single character for `true` cases and not otherwise would be "consistent".

Comment: Actually that may be pushing it, since there is no clear line between that and a no-op ("returns a mountainous string when mountainous and not otherwise") which would clearly be a loophole.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Single characters vs other strings seems a bit too fuzzy for me as well, especially since it has little relation to truthiness (only the empty string is falsy in Husk).

Comment: Yep the "any representation" is clearly too liberal - I have commented uner the OP :)

Comment: I actually want the definition to be liberal because it allows for more creative solutions. I changed the wording from 'consistent' to 'unambiguous', though I might also add that it should be unambiguous without context. As in, it should be clear without knowing what the input string was whether the result is true or false. So a single character for true and nothing for false would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 15 bytes

```
+`(.).\1
$1
^.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxtCoMwEET/7zksWAqCp@glSnGMiUZjt27WBk@fph8MDPNgeGLVP5BP9bXLl65uzs2tpaqle1PlDAJAK6@kMGygtCUreqggDm4YhwixaZuXsMwbJURffhAWCNRHJEJv/vm68OG@7AL09JaUeWLVUqz0k06jK15aj4lfVozAFZXbQ2BnbYhv) Trivial port of @ETHproductions' Japt answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

I suppose this is nearly the most straightforward method to do so?

```javascript
f=s=>(w=s.replace(/(.).\1/,"$1"))==s?w.length==1:f(w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLBbsIwDIbvfQqEdmjR1orrtnQvsotJnbaQ1iUxRDx9FwQTTLhliZSD/cWyf/9bOILXrh34racKx2KVwGL6KFUu2B0wAYDnUEfdc4hBkwaeh/YBHZ/Yga9MVVceHIb9dmd32/0NCuDbWA0cOXDArYcgNL7R1wuz08EZ3MxBySd2A58Wnl3b1@UjZcD6c615OS/U0OI/KCZqiDk@xNPURaSmNlGnaao7NXREpx2YKJU5WEsG0fq/1KoYjfKqTIPyucPBgsa0SPMs/14Xr8uX9TLLlPJfIbfY19wotX43acjGj0RT78libqlOTbqESD4GQQxH40jhq1Wk1IxBJFywitjezSwT3f/aRErLX6Ro3L447926xWJ3ixZlnFjxmR1/AA)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 72 bytes

Less trivial one, but much longer.

```javascript
s=>[...s].reduce((a,x)=>(a[a.length-2]==x?a.pop():a.push(x),a),[])==s[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZLBbsIwDIbvfQrEqUEQph23pXuQqgeTJm0hrdvEpfD0XRBMMJGWJVIiOV8s@/e/hyM4aauWNg3matyuIlhMLyGSBdleRQDwGqqxfg0RSJRA81A3KEtnsuBynRe5A6uGbn8wh313hwZwlc8GFi1YoMrBECh8J28bZruDC7ibg6IvVbd0XjiyVVMkz5QG4y655uW8Um2l/kERYolE/kCapq4ilYX2Ok1T9bnEo7LSgvZS6d4Y1EoZ95dabaNIi9GJJOWcu4xblfdSxTGsT0wkMaTAjWoKKjfvmRCnb@AttjH78HfvyvjE1sDWacaEcOlbNn5GEhuHRnGDRazjJSwZew5CMOz9FArfHBR6mvFNCA84KFje3UMT1f@6J/Qc/hKKelME@31wQTDZw/yDMk5M/sKOPw)