# Check if an array (or equivalent) has the same number of odd and even numbers - Code Golf Edition!

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, arithmetic

Inspired by [this code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242563/check-if-array-has-the-same-number-of-even-and-odd-values-in-python) question, I am curious to see what happens if we turn that into a code-golf challenge!

The description is easy, the input is an array or any similar data structure with only unsigned integers, the output is a boolean if the number of odd numbers is equal to the number of even numbers inside (true or false doesn't matter, as long as the opposite is used in case the number doesn't match)

Here are some examples with true as output for matching (thanks to the original OP)

```
[5, 1, 0, 2]      ->  true 
[5, 1, 0, 2, 11]  ->  false
[]                ->  true
```

Usual code-golf rules, shortest code wins.

Comment: Challenges should be self contained. References to external resources are welcome, but you should not rely on them. Please post some test cases here.

Comment: @manatwork true, i was going to do that but I forgot, thanks for noticing that.

Comment: May we reverse the output so that a falsy value means they are equal and a truthy value means they are not (as long as they are unique and consistent values of course)?

Comment: @ElPedro I could say no if I wanted to be strict but, why not, maybe something interesting comes out of it. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Ha, just realised that my idea is not going to work anyway but the suggestion may help someone else. One further question - if a language does not support arithmetic operations on an empty list can we ignore the empty list example (or just throw an error)?

Comment: @ElPedro sorry not empty lists exemptions, you should always consider edge cases to avoid bugs :P

Comment: Fair enough :-)

Comment: I'd like to write an answer in [COW](https://bigzaphod.github.io/COW/). But without knowing the size of the array it would be impossible. Can I add **-1** at the end of the input array?

Comment: @DomenicoModica A similar assumption has been made for the C solution. Since the input is only unsigned numbers, using a sentinel of -1 for end I think is fair. Go ahead ;)

Comment: Does it need to be a Boolean or falsy/truthy is fine as usual?

Comment: @LucaCiti Fine as usual

Answer (score 14):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 20 bytes

```hs
(==0).sum.map((-1)^)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYk9CoAgGIav8g4NChYaNHoSM5DIilQk6/p92db2/GyuHEsI5PVITGvJu3LHLrrMWKv4xCm6PUEjn3u60KAeeBgzCCgBKdBbgZ9VUF@xlp7ZB7cWauecXw)

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 33 bytes

```python
lambda l:sum(n%-2|1for n in l)==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHHqrg0VyNPVdeoxjAtv0ghTyEzTyFH09bW4H95RmZOqoKhVUFRZl6JQppGZl5BaYmGpub/aFMdBUMdBQMdBaNYLiQOkGEIFIgFAA)

`n%-2|1` is a shorter way to do`(-1)**n`. It works like this:

```python
   n  n%-2  n%-2|1
------------------
even     0       1
 odd    -1      -1
```

**36 bytes**

```python
lambda l:sum(map((-1).__pow__,l))==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TchBCoAgEEDRfaeY5QxYpNAm8CQVYpQkqA1lRKe3lu3@@/zkbU@qOD2WYOO8WAj9eUWMlhFrSY0xvN/GiECkdVvuzYcVZM@HTxkc@sRXRqIydAKkgFaAmqofvpDfmF4)

Comment: Also works in Python 3

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Thanks to [Nick Kennedy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42248/nick-kennedy) for fixing a bug after three years!

```
Ḃo-S
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of integers and yields zero (falsey) if the odd and even counts are equal or a non-zero number (truthy) otherwise.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjqZ83eD/Ryc93DnD@lHDHAVbO4VHDXNBzNK81MLSxBwgD8iBMQ@322tG/v8fHW2qo2Coo2Cgo2AEZBjG6nApgITMwQygkBGYYQiRhrGNdRRMYQpMdBTMwGxkhaj6jCGqYJoQNgK5sQA)**

#### How?

```
Ḃo-S - Link: list of integers              e.g. [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
Ḃ    - least-significant bit (vectorises)       [ 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
  -  - -1
 o   - logical OR                               [ 1,-1, 1,-1,-1]
   S - sum                                      -1
```

Alternatively, `ịØ+S`, [does the same thing](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7u7DM7SD/x@d9HDnDOtHDXMUbO0UHjXMBTFL81ILSxNzgDwgB8Y83G6vGfn/f3S0qY6CoY6CgY6CEZBhGKvDpQASMgczgEJGYIYhRBrGNtZRMIUpMNFRMAOzkRWi6jOGqIJpQtgI5MYCAA) using modular indexing.

Comment: @MarcusMangelsdorf - the 5 is the 1-based index of the rightmost zero.

Comment: @NickKennedy Oops, schoolboy error; shocking that neither I nor others noticed at the time. Thanks for the fix :)

Answer (score 5):

-2 bytes, BIG Thanks to Arnauld

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 31 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.map(e=>d+=e&1||-1,d=0)&&!d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvu/2NauWC83sUAj1dYuRds2Vc2wpkbXUCfF1kBTTU0x5X9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRrSpjoKhjoKBjoJRrKaOuoKunYJCSVFpqoK6pjUXTqVAhiFceVpiTnEqIeVGBJWjWA@U/w8A)

Comment: Based on your answer `s=>s.map(n=>c+=1-n%2*2,c=0)&&!c` - 31 bytes

Answer (score 4):

Here is my version (Thanks to @ElPedro and to everyone in the comments for the corrections):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda x:sum(i%2for i in x)==len(x)/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0VyNT1Sgtv0ghUyEzT6FC09Y2JzVPo0JT3@h/QVFmXolGmka0qY6hjoGOUaym5n84GwA)

Comment: [37](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0VyNT1Sgtv0ghUyEzT6FC09Y2JzVPo0JT3@h/QVFmXolGmka0qY6hjoGOUaym5n84GwA "Python 3 – Try It Online") if you use a lambda and lose the unneeded space between `%2` and `for`

Comment: The space in front of `for` keyword is not necessary.

Comment: [34](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0VyNT1UjLSNcwLb9IIVMhM0@hQtPW1uB/QVFmXolGmka0qY6CoY6CgY6CUaymJheSsKGOgY6RjqEhijCQ8x8A), if you port the most upvoted answer at Code Review.

Comment: 34/31 if you use `map` instead of a comprehension: `sum(map(lambda i:i%2,x))==len(x)/2` or  `sum(map(lambda i:i%2*2-1,x))==0`

Comment: I don't think the first answer is even valid, because it relies on a hardcoded list, and takes no input.

Comment: @match Save 1 byte in the first solution by replacing `lambda i:i%2` with `2 .__rmod__`.

Comment: Your TIO link has an "input" section which the program ignores.  I'd suggest removing it to leave only the footer which makes the call.  I wondered if `len/2` would fail for odd lengths, but Python 3 `/` can produce a floating-point result so `2 == 2.5` is false if you tack on another odd number.  Also remove the invalid 48-byte version; those 48 bytes include the input for this code fragment that isn't a lambda or function.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, that might be a simple solution for now. Yeah, luckily for Python 3 division always result in floating points, which will make the equality always false, which is the expected result after all.

Comment: Uh, now you only have a code fragment, not a valid program or function/lambda.  Notice how all the other Python answers use `lambda`.

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry, i'm a noob for this competition. Is there a meta post with the general rules? so that I'll read them and adapt (and add them to the questions)

Comment: [Default for Code Golf: Program, Function or Snippet?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419).  Snippets aren't allowed unless explicitly specified in the question.  (Don't change the question; requiring self-contained functions or lambdas (or whole programs) works better for code golf and is what existing answers are written for.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, completely misses that. There should be a template or something available for challenges so that it's easy to get all rules on hand. I'll edit the answer accordingly (which is a pity since print is slightly shorter than lambda)

Answer (score 4):

## perl -alp, <strike>20</strike> 19 bytes

```perl
$_=@F-2*grep$_%2,@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3tbBTddIK70otUAlXtVIx8Ht/39TBUMFAwUjLiitYGjIxWWoAIJGIIjMVjD6l19QkpmfV/xfNzGnAAA)

Just checks whether the size of the input is twice the number of odd integers. Accepts a list of space separated integers on STDIN. Prints 0 if the number of even and odd numbers are equal, something else otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 23 bytes

```ruby
->x{x.sum{|n|~0**n}==0}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukKvuDS3uiavps5ASyuv1tbWoPZ/gUJadLSpjqGOgY5RbCwXlKtgqKNgoKNgBGQYwkRjY/8DAA)

Special thanks to [Manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork), [Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus) and to [histocrat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6828/histocrat) for finding the shortest solution, all credit to them.

Comment: You know the other method is shorter in Ruby too, right? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukKvuDS3uiavJk/VSMtI17DW1tag9n@BQlp0tKmOoY6BjlFsLBeUq2Coo2Cgo2AEZBjCRGNj/wMA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: @manatwork [Even shorter](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukKvuDS3uiavJk9V16jGsNbW1qD2f4FCWnS0qY6hjoGOUWwsF5SrYKijYKCjYARkGMJEY2P/AwA "Ruby – Try It Online").

Comment: [Yet shorter](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166iukKvuDS3uiavps5ASyuv1tbWoPZ/gUJadLSpjqGOgY5RbCwXlKtgqKNgoKNgBGQYwkRjY/8DAA "Ruby – Try It Online")

Comment: Thank you all, I tried to understand all your solutions, very clever.

Didn't know that n%-2 is equivalent to -(n%2)

@histocrat would you mind explaining how the binary one's complement operator in ruby works? I don't understand how 0**5 = 0 is different from 0**4 = 0.
Thanks!

Comment: @ArmandFardeau, sure. `~` in Ruby is a two's complement negation, so `~0` is equal to `-1`. `-1` to the power of an even number is one, but to the power of an odd number is negative one. The reason we can't just do the more readable `-1**n` is that `**` has a higher precedence than `-`, so it ends up being parsed like `-(1**n)`which is always negative one.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (Kona)](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

-1 byte thanks to coltim

```
~+/-1^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNzs9L/P8/zapOW1/XMO5/mrqGqYKhgoGCkbUClKFgaGitYKBsoPkfAA)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 9 bytes

```
0=1#._1^]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DWwNlfXiDeNi/2tyKXClJmfkK2hYp2mq6dkpmCoYAhUaWcMYCoaG1goGKgYKCgr/AQ)

Ports of [xnor's Haskell solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205112/75681) - please upvote him!

Comment: You can [trim a byte](https://tio.run/##y9bNzs9L/P8/zapOW1/XMO5/mrqGqYKhgoGCkbUClKFgaGitYKBsoPkfAA) from Kona version by replacing `0=` with `~`

Comment: @coltim Yes, indeed. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 14 bytes

```
Tr[(-1)^#]==0&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277P6QoWkPXUDNOOdbW1kDtf0BRZl6JQ7qDQnUtF4JtqmOoY6BjhEVIx9Cw9v9/AA)

Comment: Perfect! ... :)

Answer (score 4):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 4 bytes

Port of @xnor's Haskell answer. In MathGolf, summing an empty list yields `0`.

```
b▬Σ┌
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/p0bQ15xY/mtLz/3@0qYKhgoGCUSwA)

### Explanation

```
b    Constant -1
 ▬   -1 ** input list (vectorizes)
  Σ  Sum the resulting list
   ┌ Convert to inverted boolean
```

Answer (score 4):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), <sup><s>25</s> <s>24</s></sup> 23 bytes

```
?0[r_1r^+z1<F]sFz1<Fd/p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/eILoo3rAoTrvK0MYtttgNRKXoF/z/b6pgqGCgYKRgaAgA)

Or verify the [test examples](https://tio.run/##RY1BCsIwFET3/xRDcCfFfsFdrCuz9QBFJSbRFNqkpAVBvHtsteBmHrxhmJsefDZ6RNWn@Ei6g5TieFIiH8o6XTld1i@W6jyoGXbT56kkevqmdUhOW7RNcATYOAXgjI8oAsRq9thXEH//kwJvWIPijuXyuw4u78AosaWFYCb6AA).

---

Input on stdin: a line of space-separated integers.

Output on stdout: `0` for truthy, and `1` for falsey (dc doesn't have standard truthy/falsey values).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 30 bytes

```python
lambda x:sum(i%2-.5for i in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrg0VyNT1UhXzzQtv0ghUyEzT6FC839BUWZeiUaaRrSxjrGOqY6hjoGOUaymJhdcHCH2HwA)

Answer (score 4):

## x86 32-bit machine code, 13 bytes

Input: `uint32_t *esi, size_t ecx`
returns: EDX = `len - 2*even` = 0 for balanced, non-zero for unbalanced.
This conveniently works even for len=0 = balanced.  As part of this asm custom calling convention / ABI, my boolean data type is 0 / non-zero, rather than the 0 / 1 that C ABIs use.

This avoids needing to actually compare, just decrement twice *inside* the loop, starting with the list length.

```
     1                         boe:
     2 00000000 89CA               mov    edx, ecx           ; balance = len
     3 00000002 E309               jecxz  .end
     4                         .loop:                        ; do {
     5 00000004 AD                 lodsd                       ; eax = *p++
     6 00000005 A801               test   al, 1
     7 00000007 7502               jnz   .odd
     8 00000009 4A                 dec    edx
     9 0000000A 4A                 dec    edx                 ; more compact than sub edx,2 in 32-bit code
    10                         .odd:
    11 0000000B E2F7               loop   .loop              ; }while(--ecx);
    12                         .end:
    13                         ;    xchg   eax, edx          ; custom calling convention: return in EDX instead of spending a byte on xchg
    14 0000000D C3                 ret
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVPBbtswDL3rK3hsFidIsrUobPS2/cOAYShoi7U1yJIhKYnTYd@ekbaHukVSDJthQCJFkY9PfBgjtaU9rRzG9nwuPeUK@Gv9QRbSfQZU9YPvB2@eAdbktFpb77scrnwFaA8/h0vW66ivhhH28AAfuuVyCE4UEy9oM9iOJR0XhLXXejA1VROqN@aF1K0PBJVvO6wSpAYdxH05NLQD4@DjblWaxAGalOTPJ7S@k4LT@irhr2NjLN2sVkzDolBCQ64KOeurphYcKGTNwRRQ7WPyLVRorXE1l3MHcsl4l0OgtA9OsHz5/HWozh6lFFpTO9jeqdr6Ei08xoQhqXGZvw5pkwGGsJ374gVfxbhu/0AqwHcCgBGdoMMYASE2PiQKYMnVqcnA89a7mj3JMyrU8EzBRwkXLgm49/VQQRoDnho1WMVUsBQisJ9jKEdu5i6ha8RpnDz7pr/fzGejN@lGct9IP5mAW8CCCYpUSQOwDl5jQiXHMopawy1nzGCTwY43Y27JxSdsvVxM1CfFmR8Pu/zC6KBNcKAQOfaVGPB/xTDNd3lKBN/4@b4zypew/v4OTARrUrK04sQGXcF0s49/od3643jZP/GrHRtvSbh7TyrYvzHh77WCopXrYokVvidtbZYPn/5NVZMYzuff) (with a `_start` test case that exits with the return value as exit status)

An alternate version that calculates in EAX to return in the standard calling convention's register is 14 bytes.  It uses `test byte [edi], 1` (1 byte longer than `test al,1`) and increments the pointer with `scasd` (without caring about the FLAGS result of the `eax - [edi]` it also does).  See the TIO link.

Uncommenting the `xchg eax, edx` at the bottom of the 13-byte version would do the same thing, and that version's loop is more efficient.

---

For 8-bit integer input, use `lodsb` instead.  Unfortunately, we can't use `and al, 1` / `add dl, al` or similar (without branching).  That would only work for array sizes up to 255.  `and eax,1` is 3 bytes.

Also, masking and adding only does one increment.  `lea edx, [edx + eax*2]` could work but that's also 3 bytes.  Branching on the low bit with test/jnz seems to be best for size, although it sucks for performance with branch mispredicts.

Of course if we wanted to go fast, we'd load 16 bytes at once with `movdqa`, isolate the low bits with `pand`, and sum with `paddd`.  Then hsum at the end.  Or hsum with `psadbw` against a zeroed register, then `paddq`.  SIMD is of course especially good for 8-bit elements, 16 per vector instead of 4, with an outer loop to avoid overflowing 8-bit counters.  e.g. [this AVX2 SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541129/how-to-count-character-occurrences-using-simd).

Something like this could maybe be smallish code-size if we limited it to a fixed-size 16-byte input array, or maybe 8-byte in MMX registers.  Unfortunately we rarely get to play with SIMD in code golf because the instructions are larger and inputs can be odd lengths requiring cleanup loops.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 7 bytes

Port of xnor's Haskell solution. Prompts for the input; -2 thanks to @Graham.

-1 byte thanks to @Adám by switching the language.

```apl
=+/¯1*⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKM97b@ttv6h9YZaj/qmgvj/07hMFQwVDBSMuOAsBUNDZI4BkPOodw0A)

Comment: Can you save 2 bytes by dropping ()∘ and replacing it by simple ⎕ input

Comment: You can save another byte by switching to Extended Dyalog APL (`=+/¯1*⎕`) or dzaima/APL (`0=1⊥¯1*`).

Answer (score 3):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), <s>17</s> 14 bytes

```
ps{2.%}pt)L[sm
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/oLjaSE@1tqBE0ye6OPf/f1MFQwUDBSMA)

Saved 3 bytes using shorthand map

Explanation:

```
ps                # Parse input as a block
  {2.%}pt         # Partition block based on modulo 2
         )L[      # Map blocks to their length
            sm    # Check lengths are the same
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Excel], 28 bytes

Paste this into a cell outside of column A, the array goes in column A.

```
=0=SUM(IF((A:A<>""),-1^A:A))
```

An example:

[image: An example]

Comment: Got some extra parens around the comparison, I think?

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 28 bytes

```java
a->a.map(n->-n%2|1).sum()==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/BSsNAEL33K8ZAYKPN0oi9pCbgwYMHUag38TCmu2VrdhN2JoGi/fZ1E@pB9PB4zLx5M28OOGJ@2H0EY/vOMxxiLQc2rbzcLP709OAaNp37VyT2Cu0kNS0SwSMaB58LgH54b00DxMiRxs7swEZNbNkbt399A/R7yuZRgGevdqZBVrcPjrfzyhp0FTCvUVrshcvr3KXXX0UmabAiq6pV2MxW3XkxogdWxOWvpQBTH6GCO@/xSOesYpqU1LeGRQJXSZZJbVpWXhDkNVyQNHRvez6KqMTbL13MJCLUXvmyHLEd1JPONucb2yOxsrIbWPbxM9YiSamElFKXLOdUS9ByYoHZ2XVaTDiFsIYCVnD9w1AUIRSR13DzDQ)

Comment: Nice job golfing it in Java!

Comment: Nice solution! I was wondering, is it really allowed in Java CodeGolf to have an IntStream as the input type? I was reluctant to use it, but i would really like to :)

Comment: @Fhuvi "the input is an array or any similar data structure", also "Usual code-golf rules", so yes...

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge-98 (PyFunge)](https://pythonhosted.org/PyFunge/), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @Jo King!*

```
#.&2%2*1-+#@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tNAtqAQz//9X1lMzUjXSMtTVVnb4/z/aVEfBUEfBQEfBKBYA)

This uses the same logic (`&2%2*1-+`) as @Abigail's answer, but has a different control flow structure. Befunge-98 adds extra "error handling" functionality to the  `&` and `~` input instructions: when EOF is reached, they reflect the instruction pointer. When this happens, the program can execute a different section of code without the need for an explicit conditional.

```
#.&2%2*1-+#@
               
               (Implicit: the counter, the top of the (empty) stack, starts at 0)
               (Implicit in program structure: begin loop)

#              Skip the next instruction
 .             (skipped)
  &            Get integer from STDIN
   2%          Take the integer modulo 2
     2*        Multiply that by 2 (results in 2 if the number was odd and 0 if even)
       1-      Subtract 1 (results in 1 if the number was odd and -1 if even)
         +     Add that to the counter
          #    Skip the next instruction
           @   (skipped)
               Repeat

When the input runs out: 
  &            Catch the EOF and reverse direction
 .             Output the counter (0 if odds and evens are matched, nonzero otherwise) as an integer
#              Skip the next instruction (a space)
           @   End the program
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <sup><s>6</s></sup> 5 bytes

-1 bytes thanks to @LuisMendo

```
oEqs~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P9@1sLju//9oUwVDBYNYAA)

### Explanation

```
oEqs~
o      % Replace each elements with its parity (i.e. mod 2)
 E     % Multiply all element by 2
  q    % Decrement all elements by 1
   s   % Sum the array
    ~  % Boolean not the sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## sed `-E`, <s>78</s> 80 bytes

*+7 to account for 0's and empty lists, -5 from golfing*

Tried to have some fun:) Input is spaced separated unary numbers.
Ex: `echo "!!! !! !!!!" | sed -Ef main.sed` (if the code is saved to main.sed)

```
s/_/@/g
s/(!!)+/@/g
s/@*!/!/g
s/ //g
:l
s/(!@|@!)//g
tl
s/!+/true/g
s/^$/false/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYq9CoAwEIP3PkUDDmqR2526@BqK4A@CtOLVzWf3bIuDIZB8JDxPzeouEaaBLK2KqQQq83Vbg5Cbphjtnnd7W1SJQ2IYCuc151df0DLuHEEESRp60ID6QzSUevwRNu9Ymu4F)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in sed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/51323/tips-for-golfing-in-sed?r=SearchResults&s=1|46.4233) page for ways you can golf your program

Answer (score 3):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 8 [bytes](https://uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
=0/+ⁿ∶¯1
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgPTAvK-KBv-KItsKvMQoKZiBbNSAxIDAgMl0KZiBbNSAxIDAgMiAxMV0KZiBbXQpmIFsxIDNdCmYgWzEgMl0KZiBbMiAyIDIgMiAxXQ==)

```
=0/+ⁿ∶¯1
    ⁿ∶¯1  # raise -1 to input
  /+      # sum
=0        # is it equal to zero?
```

Comment: Or `1` for falsy if there's more evens.

Comment: @UnrelatedString Oops, fixed for +1.

Comment: Alternative 8: `=∩/+¬.◿2`

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <s>6</s> 9 bytes

+3 bytes from fixing code per @Dominic van Essen's comment

```
~+/1 1'2!
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxVi8FugzAQRO/+io1Uqa3KxjYpFyz1RxBSXLMOCLAb20Sgqvn2kjYS7Zxm3szY8vrCJcjHfMdYKj8fquUaSguzOvpePR2t7gY1q0WF5/prXVQFSBCQK1lvAaRU4pZ34j9/vWHGWZvSRyw5N76hkx/sPiZteppNq92J9saP/DxRTJ13keeikOLATUumx86idqhD0Av6gHSeuoseyCVsdcTUEkY9ErppfKeA3qJvmvXRIF3I3XFkrCoykBmIDPIafoRvAClMBH+71cj6t7N6iMSq+3rT9mPsG0vSWQM=)

- `2!` mod the (implicit) input by two
- `1 1'` convert `0`'s to `-1`'s, leave `1`s unchanged
- `~+/` not the sum of the above

Comment: I don't think this can work for inputs with an odd-number of elements, but an even number of odd numbers, like [5 1 0 2 4]...

Comment: Good catch - revised the approach to fix that behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 4 bytes

```
ÉD¢Ë
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKfLoUWHu///jzbVUTDUUTDQUTACMgxjAQ)

### Explanation

```
É    Is the number odd?
 D   Duplicate
  ¢  Count the occurances of the bits in the original copy
   Ë Are all items in the list equal?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>45</s> <s>44</s></sup> 43 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

Saved a byte thanks to [Olivier Grégoire](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16236/olivier-gr%c3%a9goire)!!!

```c
b;f(int*a){for(b=0;~*a;b+=-*a++%2|1);b=!b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZBbS4RAFMff@xQnQfAywszYPrSTQURfoNfVB68l7NqiLhpmX92Ozrop7UO20ICI5/wv4y@0XsKw6wKRaGlWGr7eJG@5FjhUfBq@CEzHMnzTVPkH00XgXAei7XZ@mmk6NFeAB02QHXYF23jgQLMiwAhQApyAxVox0/CfGsbO6Gypm823cVbI8Q0BTKCTXVzv47CMI7mX2aM3fPVzA3K5Utz6ibv17SM@K4XA9NtW0DFY9jmGJprykOf@@xo2ii6jEAz0kCDFLCrwdSevRT0BppmOSIZrJSi9p/opDMuOMdMKNcKFxJd6x307u4TnZqOxr66wOtEGx3E6Cp/j4rAt16BGoBZoIlAR/O/KcU54qNd3zFzW@SNL/0aDXU6D/4LGNwm@nAT7FxL8chL2IhL2chJ8INF2Xw)

**Input**:

\$-1\$ terminated `int` array.

**Output**

C boolean values: \$1\$ if number of odd are equal to the number of even numbers, \$0\$ otherwise.

**How**

Initialise a counter `b` to \$0\$. Then go through the elements in the array adding \$1\$ to `b` for every odd number and \$-1\$ to `b` for every even number. Return the boolean result of testing `b` equal to \$0\$.

Comment: `b+=-*a++%2|1` to save a byte

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Nice one - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 52 bytes

```
: f ( s -- ? ) [ odd? ] partition [ length ] bi@ = ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU6xCsIwFNz9iht1iFjBpUXqJl26FKfSIbWvGmxfYpIKUvrtMYiD3HJ3HHfXy6vXNlyqojyneJBlGjBKf4ej50R8JQdjyfu3sYo9slVRpqjkSIKnsSUrdC901wnJnaAX8c92IUWPNRyEQI4NasRUjgZGWq@80hytgfgWpxq06oQjsjBjxgEJdthj@eNJ8pVLRB17m3jRYBs@)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
!sm^_1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X7E4Ny7e8P//aFMdBUMdBQMdBaNYAA)

### Explanation

```
!sm^_1
  m    : map
   ^_1 : -1 power value
       : over implicit input
 s     : sum it
!      : logical negate the sum (i.e. 0 -> True, -1 -> False, 10 -> False)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```r
!sum((-1)^scan())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X7G4NFdDQ9dQM644OTFPQ1PzvyGXEZcxlwnXfwA)

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to Bart-Jan van Rossum*

Comment: You can save 1 byte  using !sum((-1)^scan())

Comment: Thankyou!  That is clever, and I'm jealous that I didn't think of it myself.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 34 bytes

```
+>+>>,[[-[->]<]<<+[>]>,]<<[-<->]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://fatiherikli.github.io/brainfuck-visualizer/#Kz4rPj4KLFtbLVstPl08XTw8K1s+XT4sXQo8PFstPC0+XTwuCgppbnB1dDogNDgsIDQ5LCA0OCwgNDkKITAxMDE=) (Check the `!` box to enter input automatically.)

Takes input as code points. Prints a null byte if there are equal number of odds and evens. Otherwise, prints a non-null byte.

**Memory layout**:

```
a b 0 n 0
```

where `a` is the current number of odds, `b` is the current number of evens, and `n` is the current element in the array.

**Explanation**:

```
+>+>>        set a and b to 1, and pointer to n
,[           for each element n in the array
  [-[->]<]     if n is even, pointer stops at n, else, pointer stops at left of n
                 in both case, n is set to 0
                 this requires the cells left and right of n to be 0
  <<+          increment a or b appropriately
  [>]>,        pointer back to n, read new n
]            stop if n = 0 (end of array)
<<[-<->]<.   find b - a, and print that value
```

Comment: [I liked your answer :D](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/206710/75323)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brainetry](https://github.com/rojergs/brainetry), 342 bytes

Golfed version:

```
a b c d
a b
a b c d
a bb
a b
a b c d e f
a b c d e f g h
a b c d e f g h
a b c d e
a b c d e f g h
a b c d e
a b
a b c d e f g h i
a b c
a b c d e f g h i
a b c
a b c
a b c d
a b c d e f g h
a b
a b c d e f g h i
a b
a b c d e f
a b c d e f g h i
a b c
a b c
a b c d e f g h
a b c d e
a b c
a b c d e
a b
a b c d e f g h i
a b c
a b c d e f g
```

To make our lives easier we use the `--numeric-io` flag, so that we can take input and give output as integers, but we don't really need to and the answer works without it. Read the program below for due credit.

The golfed version was adapted from the program found below. To try this online you can

- head over to this [replit](https://repl.it/github/rojergs/brainetry) link, copy&paste the code into the `btry/replit.btry` file and hit the green "Run" button (takes input as ASCII characters (converts them to codepoints) and outputs ASCII characters, use CTRL-D in a newline to terminate input, doesn't really work well for this challenge.);
- clone the [github repo](https://github.com/rojergs/brainetry) and from your terminal run `./brainetry btry/ppcg/evens_and_odds.btry --numeric-io` (give one integer per line, use CTRL-Z or CTRL-D in an empty line to stop giving input).

```
"Check if an array
(or equivalent)
has the same number
of odd
and even
numbers - Code Golf Edition !"
That is the title of the codegolf.stackexchange.com challenge
that this brainetry program solves. Once more, with
no shame at all ,
I am piggy backing on someone else's answer.
This time, Surculose Sputum's answer.
Oh boy!
You can check the original answer over here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205621/75323
Go upvote that!
This is a very literal port of that answer.
I am pretty
sure I could
have used brainetry's builtins
to make this easier, like » or ≥,
except that
would mean I would have to think... ugh... nope!
For now
I will stick to the low
hanging fruit just to show that brainetry is out.
If this is
the first time
you find a brainetry program, welcome! By now
you probably understood you are
allowed to write
pretty much anything as source.
(source code)
You only have to write lines of correct size
and with the
correct line modifiers. (That's a recent addition.)
```

Comment: This is amazing, +1 for the poem

Answer (score 2):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>13</s> 10 bytes

```
÷⑷0;$Ë⑸⅀0=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N////8PZHE7cbWKsc7n40ccej1gYD2///ow11FIx0FIx1FEyAKBYA)

### Transpiled Code

```
item_split(stack)
keg_map(stack, '0;$Ë')
summate(stack)
integer(stack, 0)
comparative(stack, '=')
```

`0;$Ë` turns into:

```
integer(stack, 0)
decrement(stack)
swap(stack)
exponate(stack)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
%₂ᵍlᵐ=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X/VRU9PDrb05D7dOsP3/P9pUR8FQR8FAR8EIyDCM/R8FAA)

#### How it works

```
%₂ᵍlᵐ=
  ᵍ     group input based on result of …
%₂        mod 2
   lᵐ   map length over all groups
     =  are the lengths equal?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
$=>[0=∑map&=>[^0-1&]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?uJiHqx)

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 4 \log_{256}(96) \approx 3.29 \$ bytes

```
1n@S
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhZLDPMcgiFMqMiCDdGmOgqGOgoGOgpGQIZhLEQcAA)

Outputs `0` (which is falsy in Thunno) for `true` and something else (which is truthy in Thunno) for `false` ([meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19205/114446)).

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
1n@S0=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLDPMcgg1sIRyo2IIN0aY6CoY6CgY6CkZAhmEsRBwA)

Outputs `True` for `true` and `False` for `false`.

#### Explanation

Port of xnor's Haskell answer.

```python
1n@S0=  # Implicit input
1n      # Push -1
  @     # Get -1 ** each element of the input
   S    # The sum of the resulting list
    0=  # is equal to 0?
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 29 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(x=>i+=x%2-.5,i=0)|!i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQKPC1i5T27ZC1UhXz1Qn09ZAs0Yx839yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRrSpjoKhjoKBjoJRrKamNRdOWSDDEJsKbGLGYMH/AA)

Combined some js and py solution

If input.length==1 then a.map returns 0.5 or -0.5, treated as 0 on bool operation

+1B if returning bool required

```javascript
a=>a.map(x=>i+=x%2-.5,i=0)&&!i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQKPC1i5T27ZC1UhXz1Qn09ZAU01NMfN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmka0qY6CoY6CgY6CUaympjUXTlkgwxCbCmxixmDB/wA)

Comment: I thought how to optimize `1-x%2*2` and you did it! But you cheated a little :) You need to return `boolean` not a `number`

Comment: @EzioMercer Comes from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205166/76323)

Answer (score 1):

## jq, 24 characters

```
map(.%2)|add+0==length/2
```

Just a write of the [question owner's Python solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205104).

(Grr! 2 characters wasted because `[]|add` results `null`.)

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jq 'map(.%2)|add+0==length/2' <<< '[5, 1, 0, 2]'
true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z83sUBDT9VIsyYxJUXbwNY2JzUvvSRD3@j//2hTHUMdAx2jWAA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lU/LTsMwEDzHX7FYaZ2IlDwkTsQSHDhwQuKaWMiNHVIITogdCanttwfHraAg9cBlZ9Y7uzNec91MQlYtHySs7sBIbZ4rriUNkFeQ4jqCNIIkgowRRokZRkn@DCxJ3bDmrT5OT8QhQv2wUaYGsoPFKks0zJj@xszWUhEgD6ofjcUnqcd2JvefvayMFJY@vhGE6m6AzSyyFbC/vfiOXNyyPb4B0SFvcNsU@wG8fgCZ3nkfXC2ycMeFuEwobaV6MU2cTQTyPLdn3EUMIUbI@0dc6@8249gnto/LUu2xfT34z2z7E@9gwpwggKI40VF6TsoYLJcgq6Zz/58Tik7J6Qs)

## jq, 21 characters

```
map(.%2*2-1)|add+0==0
```

The other most efficient solution from Code Review.

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ jq 'map(.%2*2-1)|add+0==0' <<< '[5, 1, 0, 2]'
true
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z83sUBDT9VIy0jXULMmMSVF28DW1uD//2hTHUMdAx2jWAA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lU/LTsMwEDzHX7FYaTeBlDwkTsQSHDhwQuKaWMjEjloISYgdCanttwfHraAgceCyM@ud3Rk/C72epKoaMShY3YJR2jxVQisWEK/A4iqCNIIkgowjZ2iGUeGvgSWpG9ai0cfpiTgkpB82rakBd7BYZYmGGdOfmNlatgh43/ajsfio9NjM5O6jV5VR0tKHVySk7gbYzCJbgfrbs6/IxQ3f02uQHfEGt82oH8DLO@D0JvrgcpGdZ6s03AkpLxLGkgkhz3N7w52jEFJCvH9kteZuM459tH1clu2e2teD@cy239kOJtwJAiiKEx1jf0k5h@USVLXu3OfnhLJr1fQJ)

Comment: Does `jq` not have a logical negation operator that can return true for both `null` and `0`, so that you don't have to use `+0==0`?

Comment: @Neil If `jq` has one, I'd be able to golf my Erlang solution.

Comment: @Neil, in jq the only negation is the `not` filter, but as jq is quite strictly typed, all numbers are truthy: `jq -c 'map(not)' <<< '[null,0]'` results `[true,false]`. Even that `+` is working as an exception as the other arithmetic operators throw error on `null` operand.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 6 bytes

Why does need so many bytes... help!

```
EmLk%2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3zXXJ1vV6P///9GmOoY6BjpGOoaGsQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/) 18 bytes

### [Try it!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvs/R9euuDRXQ0PXUFMvLkfT1tbgv0NxRn65QppGtKGOkY6xjkms5n8A)

```
l->sum((-1).^l)==0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 19 bytes

```matlab
@(x)(~sum((-1).^x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mG/PfQaNCU6OuuDRXQ0PXUFMvrkJT83@aRrSpjqGOgY5RrCYXgqNjaIjGh8rHav4HAA)

Comment: I don't think you need the `()` around the `~sum()` statement.

Answer (score 1):

## [Golfscript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/index.html), 18 bytes

```
~.{2%},\{2%!},,\,=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v06v2ki1VicGSCrW6ujE6Nj@/x9tqmCoYKBgFAsA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-!xm`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
JpU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LSF4bQ&code=SnBV&input=WzUsIDEsIDAsIDJd)

### Explanation

The Flags:

- `!` Outputs the logical NOT of the value returned by the program
- `x` Reduces output of program on plus
- `m` Runs the program on each element in the first input, outputting an array of the results.

```
J    // The number -1
 p   // power
  U  // Input
```

---

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
!Ux!pJ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=IVV4IXBK&input=WzUsIDEsIDAsIDdd)

Same thing as above but without flags

### Explanation

```
   !pJ  // Function that does -1 ** arg
 Ux     // Map input on function then sum
!       // Logical not
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 15 bytes

```perl6
{!sum -1 X**$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1qxuDRXQddQIUJLSyW@9n9xYqVCmkKufky0nlZMrL6ea5ijj0JafpFCTmZeavH/aFMdBUMdBQMdBaNYBTDQtVNQKCkqTVXgQpIDMgxjIXJpiTnFqVzRUNUIANcHAA)

The usual not of the sum of negative one to the power of each element in the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, 22 bytes

```
[ -1 swap n^v Σ 0 = ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQVlSpkJ1alJeao5CbWJKhV5qXmZyfkgrhlKWClBYrFBSllpRUFhRl5pUoFKcWlqbmJacWK1hzVStUKxgqGCkYK5gomCrUIvFAbF1TBTMwwwBI1v6PVtA1VCguTyxQyIsrUzi3GChsqxD7PxcooPcfAA)

### Explanation:

- `-1` push `-1` to the data stack (e.g.) `{ 5 1 0 2 } -1`
- `swap` swap top two objects on the data stack `-1 { 5 1 0 2 }`
- `n^v` vectorized exponentiation `{ -1 -1 1 1 }`
- `Σ` sum a sequence `0`
- `0` push `0` to the data stack `0 0`
- `=` check top two objects on the data stack for equality `t`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
∷Ċvt≈
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oi3xIp2dOKJiCIsIiIsIls1LCAxLCAwLCAyXVxuWzUsIDEsIDAsIDIsIDExXVxuWzExLCAxLCAzLCAyXVxuW10iXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 62 bytes

```go
func(L[]int)bool{n:=0
for _,i:=range L{n+=-i%2|1}
return n==0}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fU_BCoJAEL3PVwxCoKWpQRDC9gUeuovEFm4s6WxsaxfzS7pI0Gf0If1NaoIdornMMO_Ne29u94NqXtaJ74_8kGHBJYEsTkqbuSUKYwFcuEaB7FEa4a1ea1HS3o6TVJJxdkrlFUUsAKE0bl0ZMc2plYkrmjFPThbXsAadmVITEmNBPag8O5XezHawAn8KydLF0MXAxUWKfXlrRKPLDL-xdgjTDyZ4fs4gGdhjjXdTHza6zZmTLew-cTUq1Y7zB-18fjG63fBE03z6Gw)

Answer (score 1):

## [QBasic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBasic), 38 bytes

```
1s=s+(-1)^n
INPUT n
IF n>=0GOTO 1
?s=1
```

Enter the numbers one at a time with `-1` as a sentinel value at the end. The program then outputs either `-1` (true, same number of evens and odds) or `0` (false, different number of evens and odds).

Try it at [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/msdos_qbasic_megapack)!

#### Explanation

The same "sum of \$-1\$ to the power of each number" approach as a lot of answers, with a twist. The straightforward approach is to write a loop like this:

- Input a number
- If it's -1, output the sum and quit
- Else, add \$\pm1\$ to the sum accordingly and loop

But it's golfier if we can write a simple loop with the condition at the end (`1 ... IF n >= 0 GOTO 1`) rather than breaking out of the middle. So our actual loop looks like this:

- Add \$\pm1\$ to the sum
- Input a number
- If it's nonnegative, loop
- Else, output the sum and quit

Since QBasic initializes numeric variables to 0, the first `s = s + (-1) ^ n` before any `n` has been input adds 1 to `s`. Thus, a balanced array at the end of the loop is indicated by `s` being 1, not 0.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 bytes

```
1∧2*⁻Ʃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/f8FHHciOtR427j638/z/aUMdIx1jHVMdExygWAA)

Outputs 0 (which is falsy in Pyt) for `True` and something else (which is truthy) for `False`

```
1∧        implicit print; bitwise-AND with 1 (equivalent to mod 2)
  2*⁻     double and decrement each element
     Ʃ    get sum; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 31 bytes

```sh
for i;((i%2?j++:k++));<<<$[j-k]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVnNVZpXnFqikKmQpZD9Py2/SCHTWkMjU9XIPktb2ypbW1tT09rGxkYlOks3O/Z/LVeagqmCoYKBgpECEtPQ8D8A)

Outputs `0` (truthy) if odds = evens, non-zero otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 21 bytes

```
b:0Wa{%POa?++i++b}i=b
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJiOjBXYXslUE9hPysraSsrYn1pPWIiLCIiLCIiLCInWzU7MTswOzJdJyAteCJd)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 10 bytes

```
dim(Ans)=4sum(fPart(Ans/2
```

Takes input in `Ans`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `S!`, 2 bytes

```
u@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faFm0UrCiUuyCpaUlaboWi0odlhQnJRdDuQvWRJvqKBjqKBjoKBjFQsQA)

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ñEḷạ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKw9vdH24Y_vDXQuXFCclF0NFF6yMNtQx0jHWMYuFCAAA)

##### Explanation

```python
u@  # Implicit input
u   # Push -1
 @  # Exponentiation
    # Check if the sum is 0
    # Implicit output
```

```python
ñEḷạ  # Implicit input
ñ     # Group by:
 E    #  Is even?
  ḷ   # Length of each
   ạ  # Equal?
      # Implicit output
```

Comment: [Thunno 2 `S!`, 2 bytes: `u@`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faEW0UplCsKJS7IKlpSVpuhY3FfNS0xNLMstS4_PzUhWKyxMLClJT4lMrCoDcvJLMxJLUJcVJycVQ5QvWRJvqKBjqKBjoKBjFQsQA)

Comment: @noodleman nice one! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 23 bytes

```
f(l)=0^{(-1)^l.total^2}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ouapmexzee)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/5eb2zid3t8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 15 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 1.875 bytes

```
Ǎ∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwix43iiJEiLCIiLCJbNSwgMSwgMCwgMl0iXQ==)

Uses inverted booleans (0 for truthy, any other value for falsey)

### Explained

```
Ǎ∑
 ∑  # Sum of
Ǎ   # -1 to the power of each number in the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 13 bytes

```
~.,2/\{2%},,=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/v05Px0g/ptpItVZHx/b//2hDBSMFYwWTWAA)

```
~.,2/\{2%},,=­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
~              # ‎⁡Evaluate the input string.
 .             # ‎⁢Duplicate the list on the stack.
  ,            # ‎⁣Push the length of the list.
   2/          # ‎⁤Divide it by 2.
     \         # ‎⁢⁡Swap so the original list is on top.
      {  },    # ‎⁢⁢Filter, only keeping items that
       2%      # ‎⁢⁣aren’t divisible by 2.
           ,   # ‎⁢⁤The length of the filtered list.
            =  # ‎⁣⁡Is this equal to the length of the original divided by 2?
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## APL+WIN, 15 bytes

Prompts for input of array. Can be anything from scalar, vector or multi dimensional array. TIO gives examples up to a 4 dimensional array:

```
(+/~n)=+/n←2|,⎕
```

[Try it online! Coutesy of Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcjzra0/5raOvX5WnaauvnAcWManSA0v@BEv/TuEwVDBUMFIy44CwFQyD7Ue8aIGkAxEYKRo96tzzq3WwC5BgrACGEa2QO5JsogCFUxNSMCwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Erlang (escript)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html), 40 bytes

Port of the Python answer on Code Review.

```erlang
f(I)->lists:sum([X rem 2*2-1||X<-I])==0.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYqxCsMgFEX3fMUb3yvPoEKX0GTPHwTEIRRTBE2LGrrk361jh9IzXc49LoV1fwiX78m/Su3qhjOJKfhc8pCPiGaB5CLoixbqPJebmC2No@xrXP2OxhKIqYOGfw7v5IvDDc2VFUvWloib3gMS/2hAMUgG3Yb6m36dff0A)

### Explanation

```erlang
f(I)->    % Takes an input argument
||X<-I]   % For every inputted item:
[X rem 2*2-1 % Convert X % 2 into 1's and -1's, respectively
lists:sum()  % Sum the list
==0.          % Is it 0?
```

Answer (score 0):

## Befunge-93, <strike>27</strike> 26 bytes

```
0v   @.$<
+>&:1+!#^_2%2*1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/36BMQUHBQU/FhkvbTs3KUFtROS7eSNVIy1D3/39TBSMFAwVjAA)

Prints 0 if the number of odd and even numbers are equal, something else if they aren't. Keeps track of the difference between the number of even and odd numbers seen, adding 1 for an odd number, and -1 for an even number. Prints out this difference.

Edit: Moved the `+` to the left, saving a byte.

Comment: The initial stack in Befunge is implicitly a bunch of 0s, so I don't think the first 0 is necessary in the code. Removing it and shifting everything else to the left should get it down to [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/v0xBQcFBT8WGy07NylBbUTku3kjVSMtQV/v/f1MFQwUDBSMFQ0MA).

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
¬ΣＸ±¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9jaGFyY29hbP//wqzOo@@8uMKxwrn//1tbNSwgMSwgMCwgMl1d) Port of @xnor's Haskell answer. Corresponds to the verbose code `Print(Not(Sum(Power(Negate(1), Input()))));` except that the input is implicit. Works even for zero-length arrays whose sum is `Null` rather than `0`. Note: Zero-length input arrays seem to confuse Charcoal, so input that case as `[[],[]]`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 49 bytes

```
\d+
$*
+`(^|(,))(11)*(,1|1,)(11)*($|(\2)|,)
$7
^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wPyZFm0tFi0s7QSOuRkNHU1PD0FBTS0PHsMZQB8pWqdGIMdKs0dHkUjHnilP5/99Ux1DHQMeIC0rrGBpyAQA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
(^|(,))(11)*(,1|1,)(11)*($|(\2)|,)
$7
```

Match an even number of characters that includes a single `,` and is delimited on either side by either the end of the string or a `,`, thus corresponding to a pair of numbers of opposite parity. Remove both numbers and at most one adjacent `,`.

```
+`
```

Continue to remove pairs of numbers until all remaining numbers have the same parity.

```
^$
```

Check that there are no numbers left.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
!sd(table(c(0,1,scan())%%2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/X7E4RaMkMSknVSNZw0DHUKc4OTFPQ1NTVdVIU/P/fwA)

`table` gets the counts of the unique values in the array. By appending `c(0,1)` to the array, we take care of the empty case. The standard deviation is equal to zero if and only if all the values from `table()` are equal, so we take the logical negation of that to get the result.

Alternately:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 28 bytes

```r
!any(diff(table(scan()%%2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XzExr1IjJTMtTaMkMSknVaM4OTFPQ1NV1UhTU/O/oYKRgvF/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), 52 bytes

```
procedure f(a)
(s:=0)+:=-1^!a&\z
return(s=0&1)|0
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NCoMwEITveYo1B9nQCEmhFyF9gryBtSBmCx4aJWpL/57dpqG0zmlnZj@Yru39sgyhb8nNgeCEjWA4lkaJTWkKfcya/HBngaY5eByNyrV4KkberaBz03kUDKLoQuEGFkoDWVXtJGgJSsK2lisTDx2DugbXwyNxf9Yn1n4qvIZuohG95MCF@D2mGHmxBy7jYvutXmnWGw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```lisp
(λ(a)(=(apply +(map(λ(x)(expt -1 x))a))0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcsxCgIxFIThfk8xYOEMIhjB0sM8NJHFGB7rFtmzeQevFKPVFpbzf8xkl3uc2yZbuWH6jYHXmMYSkRrfL5p4prnnBTs@zL@tirH6jH1AlUw6SE1Df45Pz7bkAiZseULAER21orUghD/YU/sA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
-*S¬
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/19XK/jQmv@H2x81rYn8/z862lRHwVBHwUBHwShWRwGJB2QYgkRAGMwwABEmQHFj89hYAA)

Could be 3 bytes under "one consistent value, one non-consistent value" rules, with `-*S` outputting 0 for true and anything else for false.

```
   ¬    Whether or not 0 equals
  S     the sum of
-       -1
 *      to the power of every element of the input (implicitly vectorized).
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: shortened both by one byte by changing `n%2*-2+1` to `n%2*2-1`*

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 28 bytes with `-p` flag

```javascript
.map((i=0,n=>i+=n%2*2-1));!i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/R9tqqNgqKNgoKNgFPtfLzexQEMj09ZAJ8/WLlPbNk/VSMtI11BT01ox839yfl5xfk6qXk5@uoZipuZ/AA)

Link leads to a TIO instance with `console.log(!i)` because I can't find out how to use the Node.js `-p` flag on TIO.

Less "cheating" answer:

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 32 bytes

```javascript
a=>(a.map(x=>i+=x%2*2-1),!i);i=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1k4jUS83sUCjwtYuU9u2QtVIy0jXUFNHMVPTOtPW4H9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaaRrSpjoKhjoKBjoJRrKbmfwA)

This link also leads to a snippet with `console.log` because I still can't figure out how to use the `-p` flag, but this one's a function.

Answer (score 0):

## Clojure (60 bytes)

```
(defn q[c](reduce = (map #(count(filter % c))[odd? even?])))
```

Ungolfed:

```
(defn eq-odd-even [c]
  (reduce = (map #(count (filter % c)) [odd? even?])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bckxCoQwEAXQ3lN8WISZbiNsKR4kWCyTEVziREOy14/22r4nMf1q1tYo6GI4vMyUNVRRjKDtu@NFkqoVWtZYNKOHMPsUwgT9q00zM3cd7Xm1Eg10wH/g8MZwzaPDuVtd0NoJ)

Answer (score 0):

## [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), 28 bytes

```
SELECT SUM(N%2*2-1)=0 FROM T
```

Inspired by [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/205103/check-if-an-array-or-equivalent-has-the-same-number-of-odd-and-even-numbers#comment486677_205104).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcZNCoAgEEDhq8wm0ChQoZW0MJkg8Ad07AYtgjZR9zdbfI/33Nf5HtUmNIRAZnGtLMAWiOstZEz0fwSC3biCGdjEByYb0Siua0aHliAXz0KnejVKPgtYU/RAtX4)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zpr'(h](https://github.com/jfrech/Zpr-h), 151 bytes

```
f|>\
```

```
(g ° (section p <$> @))
(g .l)|>((2 * (length (filter (section 0 == @) l))) == (length l))
(p ())|>0
(p (S ()))|>1
(p (S (S .n)))|>(p n)
<|prelude.zpr
```

```
test-cases |> ('\
        (' 5 (' 1 (' 0 (' 2 ())))) ('\
        (' 5 (' 1 (' 0 (' 2 (' 11 ()))))) ('\
        (' 2 (' 16 (' 3 (' 2 (' 11 (' 19 ())))))) ('\
        (' 2 (' 16 (' 3 (' 4 (' 2 (' 11 (' 19 ()))))))) ('\
        () \
    ())))))
main |> (zip test-cases (map f test-cases))
```

```
% ./Zprh stdlib/golf.zpr --de-peano
(' ((' 5 (' 1 (' 0 (' 2 0)))) , true) (' ((' 5 (' 1 (' 0 (' 2 (' 11 0))))) , false) (' ((' 2 (' 16 (' 3 (' 2 (' 11 (' 19 0)))))) , true) (' ((' 2 (' 16 (' 3 (' 4 (' 2 (' 11 (' 19 0))))))) , false) (' (0 , true) 0)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```scala
_.map(_%2*2-1).sum
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM1VlpijkGal4JNZXBLtmVcSq2BrpwCkFWz/x@vlJhZoxKsaaRnpGmrqFZfm/i8oyswrycnTSNMAqdcw1VEw1FEw0FEw0tTU5MIpCWTgVWAMUqCjYIFFjSEWMZAQV@1/AA)

Outputs 0 if there as many odd numbers as even numbers, a negative number if there are more even numbers, and a positive number if there are more odd numbers.

### Also 18 bytes:

```scala
_.:\(0)(_%2*2-1+_)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnkFpRkpqXUqzgWFCgUM1VlpijkGal4JNZXBLtmVcSq2BrpwCkFWz/x@tZxWgYaGrEqxppGekaasdr/i8oyswrycnTSNMAqdcw1VEw1FEw0FEw0tTU5MIpCWTgVWAMUqCjYIFFjSEWMZAQV@1/AA)

---

### Previous solution, 33 bytes

```scala
a=>a.count(_%2>0)==a.count(_%2<1)
```

Pretty straightforward solution. Just checks if the number of odd numbers equals the number of even numbers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYxBCsIwFET3PcVshASCNBVBxBR0J@gJRORbU0gJP8VEEcSzR7tzUd3NvHlMbMhTDufONgl7cgz7SJYvEeu@x7O4k0e7xM7FdNhyOsLU2ITgLTFMJlPTtAk3TuI0qepSGvPVV1rm/uo4eRatGC7EXEErlAqVlLL4OX7CX2E2CAqLEUePsAEVr/wG)

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, 44 bytes

```
|a|a.iter().map(|n|(n&1)*2-1).sum::<i8>()==0
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##hY1BDoIwFET3PcWHhfnfAKEkJgaBJUdwY1xUUiIJFFKKLihnr8UD6G4mM/NGL7NxrYJBdAoJVgZg5GzQWWFF0hmpkZJBTGiVRXXgdMxiTsm8DHledOcKqSxTB0AXtjHmQfu6qCtsc6iJvZ9SS8@svVN4lc2@IYgreIxjz/a7SXfK9CrAcN3CCFp8ySa4nSLgEaQRZHfy7P81L/jP6jfc3Ac)

Argument type is `a: Vec<i8>`.

`.iter()` and `::<i8>` add 13 bytes to the solution which  hurts the score quite a bit, but the compiler can't infer the `<i8>` unfortunately. If this closure accepted an iterator instead of a `Vec<i8>` (for example `std::slice::IterMut<'static, i8>`), the `.iter()` could be removed, but that seems a bit cheaty.

Comment: From what I read, this is not a valid Rust suggestion since the type can never be inferred. See https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25164/109946.

Comment: @leo848 Maybe I'm misunderstanding how meta works, but doesn't this say that types *can* be inferred? https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11223/untyped-functions-in-static-languages The post you linked was closed, referencing this post instead, and anyway was posted well after my answer was posted.

Comment: In that case, you do seem to be right. I thought that as this code can never compile as-is and requires explicit type annotations, it might not be valid.

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>84</s> 72 bytes

Saved 12 bytes thanks to [this tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153160/95792) that user41805 suggested!

```
[]*A*A.
[H|T]*E*O:-M is mod(H,2),F is E+1-M,P is O+M,T*F*P.
f(X):-X*0*0.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/PzpWy1HLUY8r2qMmJFbLVcvfStdXIbNYITc/RcNDx0hTxw3Ec9U21PXVCQAx/bV9dUK03LQC9LjSNCI0rXQjtAy0DPT@/0/TiDbVMdQx0DGK1QTJwXg6hoZQASAFAA)

`g` accepts a list, the number of even elements found so far, and the number of odd elements found so far. The base case is an empty list where the second and third parameters are the same. The second case calls `g` on the tail `T`, and increments `E` (number of even elements) or `O` (number of odd elements) depending on the head of the list, `H`. `f` is just for convenience, and starts `g` off with 0 elements of both parities.

Comment: You have to put queries in the input like so, https://tio.run/##NYuxDkAwGIR3T2H8G1dRicVmIJaGwSCRbqKRkAqDxbvXT5ju@@5y2@4WZ@Vxzt5bGgwKFCIOGOurMyjRiFzqcD7C1Y1UIxWoHisjJTXaB5tIw1KHCi0/J@r5YalHgkTE3k80ZFBsqXnn36DUV3Dc

Comment: @user41805 Thanks, I always wondered why it didn't work in the footer!

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org), 43 bytes

```rust
|a:&[i8]|0==a.iter().fold(0,|a,n|a+n%2*2-1)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqLS4ZMFN17Q8hdzEzDwNTYVqrpzUEoU0BVt9La6aRCu16EyL2BoDW9tEvcyS1CINTb20_JwUDQOdmkSdvJpE7TxVIy0jXUNNLi4t_aWlJWm6Fje1SdAG1VJhzcWVkpSuqJGmoRZtZKCjYAzEJoY6ChaxmprWCCljoCiqCFCNEVA5UFxHwRSPlI6CGaosmFcLsX_BAggNAA)

Simple functional solution. Works by first calculating the parity of the number, replacing each value by -1 if even and +1 if odd using a linear function of the remainder, and then summing the results. The sum is then compared to 0 to output a boolean.

Comment: Based on our other discussion (in my solution) - you can save a few bytes by dropping the type in the closure. Technically `.iter()` isn't necessary either, but you might want to specify that the expected type is an iterator rather than a slice or vec. Also, I love the approach of using `fold`.